# The 3 different equals

Tags: php, comparison, operators

What is the difference between `=`, `==`, and `===`?

I think using one equal sign is to declare a variable while two equal signs are for a comparison condition and lastly three equal signs are for comparing values of declared variables.

Comment: check out the example ... I have posted it would clarify more things ..

Comment: For advanced PHP users, knowing the difference between == and === and asking themself "is it faster to compare with == or with === when I'm sure that both the operands are the same type?", please look at my benchmark script below.

Comment: @Strawberry I feel  the question's tag should also include the [javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info) tag since it also applies to that language.

Comment: (Update): I have added the javascript tag in an edit, since there have been quite a few questions where people were using `=` in javascript. That doesn't only apply to PHP but other languages also.

Comment: I went ahead and deleted the JavaScript tag: all answers here are only about PHP (except the latest which is very weak), there *are* differences between how the languages handle it, and there is already a similar de facto canonical JavaScript question ([Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)).

Answer (score 179, accepted):

You have `=` the **assignment operator**, `==` the **'equal' comparison operator** and `===` the **'identical' comparison operator**.

```
$a = $b     Assign      Sets $a to be equal to $b.
$a == $b    Equal       TRUE if $a is equal to $b.
$a === $b   Identical   TRUE if $a is equal to $b, and they are of the same type. (introduced in PHP 4)
```

For more info on the need for `==` and `===`, and situations to use each, look at [the docs](http://il.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Comment: when I compare two identical datetime, I have false result, why ? example : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aef1451396f26fd6f8b623c4bb676f508c938006

Comment: @stloc, `===` with objects tells you if they are the same object, not if they have the same content.

Comment: Introduced in PHP4, funny in Y2018 ;-)

Answer (score 23):

- `=` is the assignment operator
- `==`
  is the comparison operator (checks if
  two variables have equal values)
- `===` is the identical comparison
  operator (checks if two variables
  have equal values and are of the same
  type).

Answer (score 9):

=   assignment operator

==  checks if two variables have the same value

=== checks if two variables have the same value AND if their types are the same

Comment: Also know about != and !== 'not' versions of the two comparison operators. Some languages use := as assignment, just to avoid this kind of confusion.

Answer (score 3):

The = operator assigns the value to a variable
$six = 6; value 6 is assigned to variable $six

== operator check if the value of both variables is equal and mostly used in conditions like if statements

```
$a = 2;
$b = 2;
if ($a == $b) { 
    echo both variables have the same value; 
}
```

=== operator similar to == (check if the value equals) and also check if both of same data type

```
$a = 2;
$b = "2";
if ($a === $b) {
    echo "both variable have same value and of same data type";
} else {
    echo 'both variable is either not equal or not of same data type';
}
```

// here $a is of type int whereas $b is of type string. So here the output

Answer (score 0):

For advanced PHP users, knowing the difference between `==`and `===` and asking themselves "is it faster to compare with `==` or with `===` when I'm sure that both the operands are the same type?"

The short and general answer is: **There is no performance gain in using `===` in this cases, so you should probably use `==`.**

For the ones interested in benchmarking it themselves, you can use the following code I wrote ad-hoc and try different values for `$a` and `$b`:

```
<?php
    // CONFIGURATION
    $cycles = 1000000;
    $a = 'random string 1';
    $b = 'random string 2';

    // FUNCTIONS
    function compare_two_equals($a, $b) {
        if ($a == $b) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    function compare_three_equals($a, $b) {
        if ($a === $b) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    // EXECUTION
    $time = microtime(TRUE);
    for ($count_a = 0; $count_a < $cycles; $count_a++) {
        compare_two_equals($a, $b);
    }
    $time_two_a = microtime(TRUE) - $time;
    $time = microtime(TRUE);
    for ($count_a = 0; $count_a < $cycles; $count_a++) {
        compare_three_equals($a, $b);
    }
    $time_three_a = microtime(TRUE) - $time;
    $time = microtime(TRUE);
    for ($count_a = 0; $count_a < $cycles; $count_a++) {
        compare_two_equals($a, $b);
    }
    $time_two_b = microtime(TRUE) - $time;
    $time = microtime(TRUE);
    for ($count_a = 0; $count_a < $cycles; $count_a++) {
        compare_three_equals($a, $b);
    }
    $time_three_b = microtime(TRUE) - $time;
    $time = microtime(TRUE);

    // RESULTS PRINTING
    print "<br />\nCOMPARE == (FIRST TRY): " . number_format($time_two_a, 3) . " seconds";
    print "<br />\nCOMPARE == (SECOND TRY): " . number_format($time_two_b, 3) . " seconds";
    print "<br />\nCOMPARE === (FIRST TRY): " . number_format($time_three_a, 3) . " seconds";
    print "<br />\nCOMPARE === (SECOND TRY): " . number_format($time_three_b, 3) . " seconds";
?>
```

NOTE: The comparison is valid only when each "FIRST TRY" is very close to its "SECOND TRY". If they are significantly different, it means that the processor was busy doing something else while executing the comparisons and so the results are unreliable and the benchmark should be run again.

Comment: Microbenchmarks like this are not very reliable.  It is also highly unlikely that you'd ever want to worry about `==` or `===` as the cause of your performance problem.  IMO: It's better to be strict (`===`) unless you explicitly want to be loose (`==`) about your comparisons.  The number of strange edge cases i.e. `"5 is not a number" == 5` can lead to wacky bugs. `===` never suffers from this problem.

Comment: My test was to tell programmers that if they're choosing `===` for performance reasons, they're wrong. So programmers are free to choose `===` or `==` based on logical reasons but not on performance reasons: there are different cases to prefer the one or the other and performance must not be taken into account at all.