# PHP if condition with strings

Tags: php, string, if-statement

I am trying to write would be a simple if condition.

```
function genderMatch($consumerid1, $consumerid2)
    {
    $gender1=getGender($consumerid1);
    $gender2=getGender($consumerid2);
    echo $gender1;
    echo $gender2;
    if($gender1=$gender2)   
      echo 1;
      return 1;
    else
       echo 0;
       return 0;
}
```

The output of the getGender function is either a M or F. However, no matter what I do gender1 and gender2 are returned as the same. For example I get this output: `MF1`

I am currently at a loss, any suggestions?

Comment: [This earlier answer may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if ($gender1 = $gender2)
```

assigns the value of `$gender2` to `$gender1` and proceeds if the result (i.e. the value of `$gender2`) evaluates to true (every non-empty string does). You want

```
if ($gender1 == $gender2)
```

By the way, the whole function could be written shorter, like this:

```
function genderMatch($cid1, $cid2) {
  return getGender($cid1) == getGender($cid2);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to put two == for comparison. With only one, as you have right now, you are assigning the value to the first variable.

```
     if($gender1=$gender2)
```

would become

```
   if($gender1==$gender2)
```

Answer (score 1):

this:

```
if($gender1=$gender2)
```

should be

```
if($gender1==$gender2)
```

notice the extra ='s sign.  I think you might also need curly brackets for multiple lines of an if/else statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your using the assignment operator `=` instead of comparsion operators `==` (equal) or `===` (identical).
[Have a look at PHP operators.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php)

Answer (score 1):

You have some structural problems with your code as well as an assignment instead of a comparison.

Your code should look like this:

```
function genderMatch($consumerid1, $consumerid2){
    $gender1=getGender($consumerid1);
    $gender2=getGender($consumerid2);
    echo $gender1;
    echo $gender2;
    if($gender1==$gender2){ 
      echo 1;
      return 1;
    }else{
       echo 0;
       return 0;
    }
}
```

Notice the double '=' signs in the if statement. This is a comparison. A single '=' is an assignment. Also, if you want to execute more than 1 line of code with an if/else, you need brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a single `=` which sets the variable, ie. the value of $gender1 is set to be the value of $gender2.

Use the `===` operator instead: `if($gender1 === $gender2)`. It is usually a good idea to do [strict comparisons rather than loose comparisons](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Read more about operators here: [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Another alternative is to use [`strcmp($gender1, $gender2) == 0`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php). Using a comparer method/function is more common in languages where the string-datatype isn´t treated as a primary data-type, eg. C, Java, C#.