# What is the difference between the `=` and `==` operators and what is `===`? (Single, double, and triple equals)

Tags: javascript, operators, equality, assignment-operator

I have written some code and in certain places `==` is required and in others `=` is required. Can someone explain the differences or point me in the direction of the resource that can?

Example:

```js
if($("#block").css.display == "none"){
  $("#block").css.display = "block";
}
```

The only thing I can come up with is that in one I’m changing and in the other I’m checking. But in both I am referring to equality.

Comment: = is assignment a = b means put b inside a. . == is unstrict equality, a==b means a is roughly equal to b . a===b is strict equality and the one you should be using

Comment: Any JavaScript language guide will go into details.

Comment: But to be fair until I asked this I wasn't aware of ===, so now I am in need to know what's the diff so thanks for that link.

Comment: @RKS [This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators) covers JavaScript expressions in general.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals

Comment: Note that you shouldn’t write code like in your example. Checking CSS properties directly is [best avoided](/q/55071684/4642212). Instead, a CSS class should be used, e.g. `.hidden { display: none; }`; then [`.classList.contains("hidden")`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to check for its existence, `.classList.toggle("hidden")` for toggling, etc. Consider using and [toggling](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/toggleAttribute) the [`hidden` attribute](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The 3 different equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals)

Comment: Rolled back [this revision](/revisions/11871616/6); the terms “single, double, and triple equals” help searchability.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`=` is the assignment operator. It sets a variable (the left-hand side) to a value (the right-hand side). The result is the value on the right-hand side.

`==` is the comparison operator. It will only return `true` if both values are equivalent after coercing their types to the same type.

`===` is a more strict comparison operator often called the identity operator. It will only return `true` if both the type and value of the operands are the same.

I would check out [CodeCademy](https://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript) for a quick intro to JavaScript.

If you prefer to read more, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide) is a great intro as well.

For those concerned about the source of the term "identity operator" jbabey pointed out that [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch05_04.htm) seems to mention it.

Comment: Both `==` and `===` check the types of the operands. It's what they may do with the result of those checks that differentiates them.

Comment: @jbabey Could you provide a source for "identity operator"?  ECMA-262 refers to it as "The Strict Equals operator."

Comment: @Dennis i think it may have been on MDN at one point in time. I'm not sure where it originated, but it is a fairly common phrase (google for "javascript identity operator")

Comment: @Dennis ah, here we go. The very widely known book [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch05_04.htm) uses the term "Identity operators". it probably originated here (or at least became much more common).

Answer (score 6):

`=` assigns a value to a variable

`==` checks if the two parameter are equal to each other

`===` checks if the two parameters are equal to each other **and** if their type is the same

---

`!` not operator

`!=` checks if the two parameters are not equal to each other

`!==` checks if the two parameters are not equal to each other **or** the type is not the same

---

### one more

`>` checks if one parameter is greater than the other

`>=` checks if one parameter is greater than or equal to the other

`>==` DOESN'T EXIST

---

### etcetera...

Comment: i think you meant: "checks if the two parameters are not equal to each other **OR** the type is not the same". DeMorgans :P

Answer (score 4):

== is used to test if the value on the left is equal to the value on the right.

= is used to assign the value on the right to the variable on the left.

Answer (score 3):

In javascript you have also the ===.

`=`      This is for set the value to the variable.

`==`     This is for compare if the value is the same.

`===`    This is for compare if the value is the same and also the type is the same.

Answer (score 3):

The = operator is an assignment operator.  You are assigning an object to a value.  The == operator is a conditional equality operation.  You are confirming whether two things have equal values.  There is also a === operator.  This compares not only value, but also type.

[Assignment Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators)

[Comparison Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)