# Jquery If,Then - Multiple Variables

Tags: jquery, arrays, if-statement

Running into a roadblock with multiple variables and jquery if/then.

What I would like to do is when a user selects a specific state a calculation is done.

This is what I have so far but it is not working:

```
var zonea = ("NY", "NJ", "DE");

$('#states').change(function () {
var w = +$('#states').val();
if (w == zonea) {
alert("Good!");
}
})
```

If I change the code to:

```
var zonea = ("NY", "NJ", "DE");

$('#states').change(function () {
var w = +$('#states').val();
if (w = zonea) {
alert("Good!");
}
})
```

no matter what state I select the alert is shown.

Am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Possible Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871616/in-javascript-vs

Comment: Also, `var zonea = ("NY", "NJ", "DE");` doesn't make a whole lot of sense. It is equivalent to `var zonea = "DE";`

Comment: What I am trying to do is assign multiple states to a var zonea. So that, if a user selects any of the 3 states the alert comes up.

Comment: if (w = zonea) {... should be if (w == zonea) {

Comment: A variable can only contain one value. Maybe you insted meant for it to contain an array that has multiple values?

Answer (score -1):

In the second case

```js
var w, zonea;
zonea = false;
if (w = zonea) {
    alert("Good!");
    }
```

you are assigning the value `zonea` to `w` in if condition and so apart from a `0` or a `false` value for `zonea` the condition will be true and hence the alert will be executed

Answer (score -1):

```
var zonea = ("NY", "NJ", "DE");
$('#states').change(function () {
var w = +$('#states').val();
if (w = zonea) {
alert("Good!");
}
});
```

Here you use = which mean assign value and always it will be true to compare two values you have to use == with in your if statement.
Also I see that the + sign in var w is not needed and may result in code error, when you define w it will be string and zonea is array so try to use indexOf instead of w==zonea