# How do you make a variable that says hi if hit once and you already clicked me if hit again?

Tags: javascript

I tried

```js
function myFunction() {
  alert("hi")
  myvar == 1
}
var myvar = 0;
if (myvar == 1) {
  alert("you already clicked me!")
 }
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">hi</button>
```

but that did not work.

I want one to work for a game I am making in pure code.  If you place a wall (hit the button) it will say wall placed. If you try to hit the button again, it will say wall already placed, because you can not place a wall inside of a wall.

Comment: First, the `if (myvar == 1) {
  alert("you already clicked me!")
 }` needs to be within the function, or else it will be evaluated at load. Second, reread on how [operators work, especially `==`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871616/in-javascript-vs)

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
var myvar = 0;
function myFunction() {
  alert(myvar === 0 ? "hi" : "you already clicked me!")
  myvar = 1;
}
```

there was few errors in you code -

assignment was wrong (this was equality) -

```
myvar == 1
```

the second rule should be inside the function

```
if (myvar == 1) {
  alert("you already clicked me!")
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the check for the variable value and the increasing of the variable inside of the function of course.

The line `myvar == 1` itself will actually result in the boolean `false` and is not assigned to a variable, so it won't do anything.

```js
var myvar = 0;

function myFunction() {
  if (myvar > 0) {
    alert("you already clicked me " + myvar + "x!")
  } else {
    alert("hi")
  }
  myvar = myvar + 1; // or myvar++;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">hi</button>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Now time to make that game!