# FOR LOOP with nested IF statement

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I have some code which loops through an array and adds the data to a HTML table.

For one of the fields 'Unit_Sell', I would like to prefix the HTML with a '£' symbol.

Here is what I have tried.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   var node = win.document.createElement("tr")

   for (var key of ['description', 'ref_date_start', 'ref_date_end', 'unit_sell', 'qty', 'price']) {
     var tb = win.document.createElement("td")

     if (key = 'unit_sell') {
       tb.innerHTML = '£' + arr[i][key]
     }

     tb.innerHTML = arr[i][key]
     tb.style.paddingLeft = "30px";
     node.appendChild(tb)
   }
 }
```

The loop works fine, but the if statement condition is not being met.

Comment: `if (key = 'unit_sell')` [single `=` is for *assignment*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871616/in-javascript-vs/). To do an equality check use `==` or `===`

Comment: Change to `key == 'unit_sell'`.  You need a double `=` for `if` comparison.

Comment: Even after fixing the typo, you have `tb.innerHTML = ` after the if block which is going to overwrite everything. So it will overwrite the code you set in the if block

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I needed to add the second "tb.innerHTML =" into an ELSE on the FOR LOOP. Please add as an answer and I will accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out already you need to compare `key` to `'unit_sell'` instead of assigning. However you also need an `else` branch, otherwise the `innerHTMl` from within the condition will be overwritten.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var node = win.document.createElement("tr")

  for (var key of ['description', 'ref_date_start', 'ref_date_end', 'unit_sell', 'qty', 'price']) {
    var tb = win.document.createElement("td")

    if (key === 'unit_sell') {
      tb.innerHTML = '£' + arr[i][key]
    } else {
      tb.innerHTML = arr[i][key]
    }

    tb.style.paddingLeft = "30px";
    node.appendChild(tb)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with comparison. You put:

```
if (key = 'unit_sell') {
```

When it should be:

```
if (key == 'unit_sell') {
```

The way you wrote it, you are using *assignment* instead of *comparison*.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, care to explain why this answer is insufficient?

Comment: I didn't down vote, but I'm guessing it was downvoted due to the `tb.innerHTML = arr[i][key]` line not being in an `else` block after your `if` statement.

Comment: Ah ok, that's fair. I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

```
   if (key == 'unit_sell') {
        tb.innerHTML = '£' + arr[i][key]
    }
```

And a great tutorial for JS 
https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS