# Writing an If statement to = a number but not allow for than another

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, user-object

Im writing an if statement that allows to display a choice based on users input,

Im basically trying to say if something like if they pick 2-4 guests then allow the option.

This is what i've written:

```js
if (userObj.guests = 2 || userObj.guests <=4 && userObj.dayDifference <=10 ) {
    $('.motel_container').removeClass('disable')
}
```

How can i only allow the if statement to work if they pick 2 - 4 guests only.

Comment: `userObj.guests = 2` using a single `=` is an *assignment*. If you want to check for equality, use `==` or `===`.  [In javascript == vs =?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871616/in-javascript-vs)

Comment: Also `userObj.guests == 2 || userObj.guests <=4` doesn't make a lot of sense - `2` is already `<= 4`, as is `1`. So, if you have `userObj.guests = 1`, then `userObj.guests == 2` is `false`, yet `userObj.guests <= 4` is `true`.

Comment: need to fix your conditions as well, should be ```guests >=2 && guests <=4 && diff <=10```

Comment: I think this would help you.

Below the new Code:

```
if ((userObj?.guests == 2 || userObj?.guests <= 4) && userObj?.dayDifference <= 10 ) {
    $('.motel_container').removeClass('disable');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript a single '=' is used for assigning a variable, while '==' or '===' are used to compare values.

To check if the user chose between 2 to 4 nights:

```
if (nights >= 2 && nights <= 4) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the first predicate inside the if statement.

You need to change it from:

```
userObj.guests = 2
```

to

```
userObj.guests == 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (userObj.guests >= 2 && userObj.guests <=4 && userObj.dayDifference <=10 ) {
    $('.motel_container').removeClass('disable')
}
```

This will check if the number of guests is:
- greater or equal to 2
- AND smaller or equal to 4
- AND day difference is smaller or equal to 10

PS: I'm confused. You're talking about 2 - 4 *nights*, but your code is referencing 2 - 4 *guests*.

Comment: sorry typo meant guests

Answer (score 0):

You are using assignment operator i.e.(=). if you want to compare then you should use something like (==, >= , <=). In your case, code should be like

```
if (noofNights >= 2 && noofNights <= 4) {
    // apply code
}
```