# add text to element when checkbox is true

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets

Hi I'm trying to insert a value from my google sheet next to my materialize checkbox if the checkbox is true i need it to return the value from my google sheet if the checkbox is false it would leave it blank I've tried all kinds of ways but cant get it to work.

HTML

```
   <form action="#">
     <p>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id ="NewJobSW" class="filled-in" >
        <span for="NewJobSW">New Job</span>
      </label>
    </p>

  </form>
   <div>
    <h5><span  id='getNJ'> </span></h5>
   </div>
```

JS code

```
     <script>
          <?
          var sheet   = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1QMgcxD4ujIE95a3GbA5hVU8lXrackjTwdHECqY0ks").getSheetByName("HelpSheet");
          var data = sheet.getRange("D2").getValue();
          ?>
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getNJ).getNJ();

          function getNewJob(getNJ){

              var triger= document.getElementById("NewJobSW").value;  
                   if(triger = true){                 
                       document.getElementById('getNJ').innerHTML = getNJ
                    }else if(triger = false){
                         document.getElementById('getNJ').innerHTML = ""

                    }
      </script>
```

Thanks

Comment: `<?` and `?>` isn't valid JavaScript. Are you using a server side scripting language like PHP?

Comment: You may want to use comparison operators (`==`) instead of assignment operators (`=`); see [== vs =](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871616/in-javascript-vs).

Comment: You are using Apps Script methods (e.g. `openById`) in client-side. This cannot work. Are you trying to publish an Apps Script web app? Can you provide the rest of the code you're using, if any?

Answer (score 0):

A checkbox can only be checked in this way...

```
 if(NewJobSW.checked){getNJ.innerHTML='123';} else {getNJ.innerHTML='0';}
```

NB: I used "123" as an example but you'll have to assign the value properly from your spread sheet.