# Hide rows if cell is populated

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to hide rows when a cell says "Approved", this is what i have so far but it appears to be hiding all data even when "B:B" is "Pending"

```html
 function ConditionalHideRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var condition = sheet.getRange("B:B").getValue();
  if (condition = "Approved") {
    sheet.hideRows(1,25)
   }   
   }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In javascript == vs =?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871616/in-javascript-vs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function ConditionalHideRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var values=sheet.getRange(1,2,sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  values.forEach(function(r,i){
    if(r[0]=='Approved') {
      sheet.hideRows(i+1)
    }
  });
}
```

[Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, sorry new to scripting!, what does the [i] and [0] represent? @Cooper

Comment: Sorry I had to make an edit.  I'm still a bit old school in my Javascript.  But they are array indices.  The getValues() method returns a two dimensional array.  It's somewhat explained in the reference in my answer.

Comment: Hello, Is there a way to update this to hide rows if collumn also states rejected, so only show blanks