# Form element wont hide after sending message

Tags: javascript

After submitting, I want to hide my form elemnt from page. I've tried using myForm.style.display == "none" but it doesn't work. Can someone assist me?

```
let myForm = document.getElementById('contact-form');
  
  myForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData(myForm);

    fetch('@/api/contact_form_messages', {
      method: 'post',
      body: formData
    })
    .then((checkStatus))
    .then((response) => {
      document.getElementById("success-msg").innerHTML = "Success";
      myForm.style.display == "none";
      return response.text();
    })
```

Comment: Dupe: [In javascript == vs =?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871616/in-javascript-vs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *assign*, not compare, this is incorrect:

```
myForm.style.display == "none"; // Incorrect
```

This is correct:

```
myForm.style.display = "none"; // Correct
```

Comment: Enough rep to comment and vote to close as typo-type?

Comment: @mplungjan I have voted to close based on a typo. Also answered to help OP understand (format of an answer is more clear than wedging code into comments).

Comment: Dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871616/in-javascript-vs