# TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'x' of object '[object Array]'

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I've tried to change this so many ways, no matter how it's done/explained on other Stack Overflow posts. I have an array of objects, and I am trying to map/loop through the array move one of the objects to the front of the array.

Here's what I've got:

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState<User[]>([]);
const [primaryUser, setPrimaryUser] = useState<User>({
  id: 0;
  first_name: "",
  last_name: ""
})

useEffect(() => {
  users.map((user, i) => {
    if(user.id === 12345) {
      users.splice(i, 1);
      users.unshift(user)

      setPrimaryUser(user);
    }
  });

  setUsers(users);
}, [])
```

Whether I map as shown above or use a for loop, I always end up getting the following error: `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'x' of object '[object Array]'`

Any suggestions/help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `if(user.id = 12345)` [this is assignment, not equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871616/in-javascript-vs/). Moreover, you should probably avoid mutating `users` via `.splice()` and `.unshift()`. Also, as a side note, please don't use `.map` as a simple iteration. If you're not doing a mapping operation, use `.forEach` or a simple loop.

Comment: Thanks, I copied it over incorrectly. I have it as `if(user.id === 12345) {`. Also, I've tried a `forEach` and `for` loop. Still getting the same error every time.

Comment: Then the issue is with mutating the array. You should never mutate state directly with React and this is exactly the problem you get here.

Comment: I've even tried making a copy of the state - `let tempUsers = users`, mutating that, setting it - `setUsers(tempUsers)` and still the same thing.

Comment: `let tempUsers = users` will ***not*** make a copy of the array! [Copy array by value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7486085)

Comment: not sure if this is related or just a typo in copying your example, but you've got a semicolon after `id: 0;` in your primaryUser userState call

Answer (score 1):

I see the code is used in React, so it is best to avoid modifying the `users` array in place (for example with `.unshift()` or `.splice()`) as React will not see the difference and will not re-render.

It is common practice in React to create new value for the previous one.

I think you can achieve the goal by [filtering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the `users` array twice (filter method creates a copy without affecting the original):

- users with id 12345 - expecting just one and and store it in `primaryUser` variable
- users with id not 12345

and combining those arrays:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const primaryUserID = 12345;
  const [ primaryUser ] = users.filter(user => user.id === primaryUserID)
  setPrimaryUser(primaryUser);

  // Construct array from 'primaryUser' and the rest of users
  const newUsers = [
     primaryUser,
     ...users.filter(user => user.id !== primaryUserID),
  ];
  setUsers(newUsers);
}, [])
```

Comment: Here's great article about JS array methods, it explains filter/map/reduce using good examples https://www.telerik.com/blogs/functional-programming-with-javascript-object-arrays

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both VLAZ and Vitalii (great article), I was able to get it working. Here was my solution:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let tempUsers = [...users];

  tempUsers.map((user, i) => {
    if(user.id === 12345) {
      tempUsers.splice(i, 1);
      tempUsers.unshift(user)

      setPrimaryUser(user);
    }
  });

  setUsers(tempUsers);
}, [])
```

THANK YOU!