# read tabel value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

good morning
i wanna try to hide an icon using jquery in table data, if table data value reject then icon hide.
but it doesnt seem right

```
<tr>            
    <td id="status"><?php echo $row[PO_Status]; ?></td>
    <td>
        <center>
            <a id="edit" href="./page.php?page=editdatapo&id=<?php echo $row[id]; ?>">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
               </button>
            </a>
        </center>
    </td>
</tr>
```

```
<script>
    $("#status").each(function() {
    var status = $(this).text();
    console.log(status);
    });
if (status = 'reject'){
$("#edit").hide();
}
</script>
```

i have 4 td Approve,Approve,reject,reject
when i check console it print Approve,Approve,Approve,Approve

Comment: In HTML, [IDs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) must be unique to the DOM tree. In other words, only one element can have the ID "status". You might try using a different ID for each element or (better yet) a common [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors). Also see [Does ID have to be unique in the whole page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page)

Comment: i already check ID status is uniqe

Comment: You mentioned you have four `<td>` elements. What are the IDs for the other three?

Comment: <?php echo $row[PO_Status]; ?> i mean i have result from php at td id="status"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per HTML Standard you can give id only on time in a page, If there are 1 id multiple time then you have to use find().

```html
<script>
    $("tr").find("#status").each(function() {
        var status = $(this).html();
        if (status == 'reject'){
            $(this).parent("tr").find("#edit").hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

[IDs must be unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page) to the HTML DOM tree.
For recurrent use, I recommend using classes instead.

The condition to test `status` against "reject" should go inside the `each` loop.
You're testing each element to see if its status is "reject".

The `=` assigns a value while `==` [compares equivalence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11871654/924299).

You'll need to traverse from the clicked `.status` to its associated `.edit` element in the next cell. I do this by moving up to the closest `<tr>` and then searching for the `.edit` element within that row.

```js
$('.status').each(function() {
  let $this = jQuery(this);
  let status = $this.text();
  console.log(status);
  if (status == 'reject') {
    $this.closest('tr').find('.edit').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="status">one</td>
      <td>
        <center>
          <a class="edit" href="./page.php?page=editdatapo&id=1">edit</a>
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="status">reject</td>
      <td>
        <center>
          <a class="edit" href="./page.php?page=editdatapo&id=2">edit</a>
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="status">three</td>
      <td>
        <center>
          <a class="edit" href="./page.php?page=editdatapo&id=3">edit</a>
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```