# Push into array of Objects

Tags: typescript

I have an array with objects:

```js
const teams = [{
  TeamId: "asfqef",
  Projects: [{
    ProjectId: "wfwef",
    TeamId: "asfqef"
  }]
}];
projectCreated ={ProjectId: "aaaa", TeamId: "asfqef"};
```

so I need to push a Project into a especific Team, so for that I make It:

```js
this.teams.forEach(team => {
  if (team.TeamId = projectCreated.TeamId ){
    team.Projects.push(projectCreated);
  }
});
```

My problem is that it is inserting the Project into all the Teams, so what's wrong with my logic?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In javascript == vs =?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871616/in-javascript-vs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `=` operator in the `if` statement. It will be always evaluated as `true`.

```
if ( team.TeamId === projectCreated.TeamId )
```

Update the code like the above.

Comment: That moment in that you need to get away of work