# How do I create a checkbox statement in onclick attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to figure this out for 2 days, but I couldn't find any solutions.

What I want is, every time I check the checkbox, an element's property will change(i.e. BGcolor of the body). but it only works when the checkbox is checked, but it doesn't work when the checkbox is unchecked.

```js
var checkboxStatus = document.getElementById("menuCheckBox");
function menuToggle() {
    if (checkboxStatus.checked = true) {
        document.body.style.background = "cyan";
    } else {
        document.body.style.background = "magenta";
    }
}
menuToggle();
```

```html
<input id="menuCheckBox" type="checkbox" onclick="menuToggle()"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, just wrong use of operators. You used a single = instead of two. Boolean statements (comparison) needs two equals signs. https://www.guru99.com/difference-equality-strict-operator-javascript.html

```js
var checkboxStatus = document.getElementById("menuCheckBox");
function menuToggle() {
    if (checkboxStatus.checked == true) {
        document.body.style.background = "cyan";
    } else {
        document.body.style.background = "magenta";
    }
}
menuToggle();
```

```html
<input id="menuCheckBox" type="checkbox" onclick="menuToggle()"/>
```

You can also omit the `== true` entirely, as a true boolean statement is true itself without being compared to true.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**
In this line

```
if (checkboxStatus.checked = true) {
```

**Solution:**
There are 2 ways to resolve your problem:

1. Make `==` instead like this: `if (checkboxStatus.checked == true) {`
2. Remove `=` like this: `if (checkboxStatus.checked) {`

**Explain:**

- `=` is the assignment operator. *It sets a variable (the left-hand side) to a value (the right-hand side).*
- `==` is the comparison operator. *It will tell you whether or not two values are equivalent regardless of the type of the operands.*

**Read more:**

- [In javascript == vs =?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871616/in-javascript-vs)
- [JavaScript Comparison and Logical Operators](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

**Refactor code:**

```js
var checkboxStatus = document.getElementById("menuCheckBox");
function menuToggle() {
    const backGroundCorlor = checkboxStatus.checked ? "cyan" : "magenta";
    document.body.style.background = backGroundCorlor;
}
menuToggle();
```

```html
<input id="menuCheckBox" type="checkbox" onclick="menuToggle()"/>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help. @Vladd Cantor  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

here you go

```js
function colorchange() {
  if (document.getElementById('checker').checked) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
  } else {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="colorchange();" id="checker"></input>
```