# How to make the clearInterval work and why isn't it working?

Tags: javascript, function, setinterval, clearinterval

I have a condition here which is if `a = 6`, stop the `setInterval` so I used `clearInterval` for my condition, but it doesn't take effect, anybody can help me how I can make the `clearInterval` work under that condition?

Please take note that in my case makig `doSomething` to execute after some amount of time is of paramount importance as well, that's why I used `setTimeout` here.

```js
function doSomething() {

  let a = 1;

  return setInterval(() => {
    if (a < 6) {
      a++;
      console.log(a);
    } else {
      a = 1;
    }
  }, 1000)
}

setTimeout(doSomething, 5000);

var id = doSomething();

if (a === 6) {
  clearInterval(id);
}
```

Comment: `a` is not defined outside of `doSomething`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: @HereticMonkey No I know the concept of variable scopes, even if I put that `if (a = 6) {
  clearInterval(id);
}` inside the doSomething function, it doesnt work, I just don't know how to make it work.

Comment: You have to call `clearInterval` inside the interval callback. [Stop setInterval call in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/109086)

Comment: Off topic - In your if statement you are assigning (`=`) not comparing (`==`) `6` to the variable `a`. `6` is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) so the if statement will always execute.

Comment: You have two intervals going; the one started in `setTimeout(doSomething, 5000)` and the one started in `var id = doSomething();` Even if `if (a = 6)` was able to access `a` (which it can't), and it used a comparison operator, like `==`, which it doesn't, it would still only clear the second interval .

Comment: `if (a = 6)` is *assignment, not an equality check. See [In javascript == vs =?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11871616)

Comment: @VLAZ Yeah that was a typo, but I still don't know how to fix this...

Comment: @Dorothy did you look at the first link I posted which is about stopping intervals?

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, I'm trying to use that way, the difference is that I have an arrow function inside `doSomething` that I can't seem to handle it.

Comment: @VLAZ Do you know a solution to my problem? The answer that dude just posted doesn't appeal for the `doSomething` to execute after some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `clearInterval` inside the `setInterval` - I think this is what you're trying to achieve:

```js
let intervalId;

function doSomething() {
  let a = 1;

  return setInterval(() => {
    console.log(a);

    if (a++ === 6) {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

setTimeout(() => {
  intervalId = doSomething();
}, 5000);

console.log('Waiting for 5 seconds before calling doSomething..');
```

Comment: Thsnks, but how can I make `doSomething` execute after some time?

Comment: Thanks but how can I make the `doSomething` to execute after some time? Using `setTimeout(doSomething, 5000)` seems to make clearInterval not to work.

Comment: @Dorothy I've update the code example to address your comment that you want it to wait for some time before calling the `doSomething`