# Variable Set to undefined

Tags: javascript, variables

I am fairly new to Javascript and i ran into a problem when creating a chess game . I have already made the board, but when i tried incorporating JS code that would move these peices when i clicked on them, a problem arose. See i declared the variable "x" to hold the value of the chess peice value that had been clicked on when count=0 but when i tried it out, the code just outputs x as 'undefined'.What have i done wrong, any help would be appreciated :)

(below is a snippet of my JS code)

```
<div onclick="changeText(63)"id="63"class="black">&#9816;</div>
<div onclick="changeText(64)"id="64"class="white">&#9814;</div>
</div>
<script>
var count = 0;
var x;
function changeText(id) {
    if (count > 1){
        count = 0;
    }
    if(count=0){
        x = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
        document.getElementbyId(id).innerHTML="";
    }
    if(count=1){
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=x;
    }
    count = count + 1;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Two things. 1) `count=1` means you're _assigning_ `1` to `count` not checking to see if that's the value. That should be `count === 1`.  2) In that condition `x` _is`_ undefined.

Comment: @Andy also `count=0` will *skip* the condition that assigns `x`

Comment: [In javascript == vs =?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11871616)

Comment: Three things, then. :)

Answer (score 1):

The second and third  `if`  statements will not be evaluating the variable value - because rather than comparison (`count=== 0`) what happens there is a variable assignment (`count = 0`).

The `if (count = 0)` is evaluated to `false`, so, the variable `x` never gets a value.

On the other hand `if (count = 1)` is evaluated to `true`. So, the HTML element gets an undefined string. Your code should look like this:

```
...

if (count === 0){
    x = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
    document.getElementbyId(id).innerHTML="";
}

if( count === 1){
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=x;
}
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Comment: I put alert("Count=0"); in the first if statement and alert("Count=1"); in the second if statement to see if it was setting count to 1 but no matter when and where i clicked i got the alert: "Count=0".

Comment: The alert prints your string.

Comment: yes but it should alert me with "Count=1" every second time i click on a square, as i put the different alert statements in separate if statements

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the id to that handler function if it's doing the same thing. If you want a function that changes the innerHTML of the thing that was clicked, try passing `event` to the handler, and then using `event.target.innerHTML` like this:

```html
<div onclick="changeText(event)" class="black">&#9816;</div>
<div onclick="changeText(event)" class="white">&#9814;</div>

<script>
function changeText(event) {
    if (event.target.innerHTML === 'x') {
    event.target.innerHTML = 'y' // you can do anything here
  } else {
    event.target.innerHTML = 'x'
  }
    
}
</script>
```