# if conditions in while loop

Tags: javascript, passwords, weekday

while loop with a if statement is not printing my if statement

```
var rest = 0
while(rest <=10) {

   rest ++;
   console.log(rest);

   if (rest == 10)
      console.log('Done!')
```

Comment: 1. [`=` is assignment, not equality check.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871616/what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-operators-and-what-is-si) 2. This is not how [`switch` should be written](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

Comment: soooo ... can you help me ?

Comment: you cannot change the whole question a few months after you posted it, you must create a new one. The goal behind StackOverflow is that people with the same question as you can go to this page, see the answer you got and not ask it again on SO or another forum. If you change the question people won't be able to know if it solved their problem.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to approach this would be to use [Date#getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) to get the `0-6` index of the current day within the week and store the suffixes in an array with same indexing.

Then use the day index to retrieve the associated suffix.

```js
const suffixes = ['snd','mnd','tsd','wdnsd','thrsd','frd','strd']

const weekPass = 'ABC_';

const day = (new Date()).getDay();

const pass = weekPass + suffixes[day];

console.log('Day index =',day, ', Passs =',pass )
```

Comment: this is what they ask me to do : "Having got the value of the weekly password stored in weeklyPass, update and print to the console the value of currentPass depending on the day of the week we are in. To know which day of the week it is simply access weekDay. Remember that updating the password is appending the letters corresponding to the consonants present in the name of the current day of the week. There are many ways of cracking this problem, but Elliot and the guys specifically asked for you to use a switch statement..."

Comment: Well as mentioned in comments above you are not using the switch correctly. Also be careful with case differences ... "Friday" does not equal "friday"

Answer (score 0):

Or just this

```js
const currentPass = "aaa",
  weekDay = new Date().getDay(), // 0-6 (sun-mon)
  dayPass = currentPass + ['snd', 'mnd', 'tsd', 'wdnsd', 'thrsd', 'frd', 'strd'][weekDay];
  
  console.log(dayPass)
```

Comment: this is what they ask me to do :
"Having got the value of the weekly password stored in weeklyPass, update and print to the console the value of currentPass depending on the day of the week we are in. To know which day of the week it is simply access weekDay.

Remember that updating the password is appending the letters corresponding to the consonants present in the name of the current day of the week.

There are many ways of cracking this problem, but Elliot and the guys specifically asked for you to use a switch statement..."

Answer (score 0):

Considering what you wrote, the first step to get it working would be to fix the [switch syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) and the assignment of `currentPass` like this:

```js
var weekDay = 'Friday';
var currentPass = "this_week_password"; // this is the values they gave me
switch (weekDay) {
    case 'Monday':
        currentPass += 'mnd';
            break;
    case 'Tuesday':
        currentPass += 'tsd';
            break;
    case 'Wednesday':
        currentPass += 'wdnsd';
            break;
    case 'Thursday':
        currentPass += 'thrsd';
            break;    
    case 'Friday':
        currentPass += 'frd';       
            break;
    case 'Saturday':
        currentPass += 'strd';
            break;
    case 'Sunday':
        currentPass += 'snd';
            break;
    }

console.log(currentPass)
```

Comment: I forgot to say that they give me this value :
var weeklyPass = 'darlene';

Comment: So just replace `"this_week_password"` by `weeklyPass`

Comment: this is what the say : >>>>Code is incorrect
Think about what possible cases there are for the value you are evaluating and see if you aren't missing some.