# undefine keep on appearing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, addeventlistener

I have been battling with this code since couple of days and its giving me issue. the other functions are working perfectly except this EQUAL function.

Below is the code

```
equal.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        if (screen.value = "") {
           screen.value = "";
         } else{
             console.log(screen.value);
             let answer = eval(screen.value);
             screen.value = answer;
         } 
     });
```

Comment: Do you know how to use your browser to debug JavaScript? A little scrutiny of each line's value as it runs would've made the mistake fairly apparent. Try setting a breakpoint on line 2 and selecting `screen.value = ""`.

Comment: see: [What is the difference between the `=` and `==` operators and what is `===`? (Single, double, and triple equals)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871616/what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-operators-and-what-is-si)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing jumping out to me is that you're using the assignment operator rather than comparison in the `if` statement. Maybe this resolves your issue:

```
if (screen.value == "") {
           screen.value = "";
         } else{
```

Comment: Thank you for the response and help , however, i have tried it and it doesn't work either