# Getting a result after mutliple variables in javascript

Tags: javascript

I´m pretty new to coding and I´ve been trying to get a website running where there are multiple forms, I want to get different outputs depending on the interaction of the various answers.
As of now I get a change in the console congruent with the selected element, it seems to be working, the variables being:

```
let a = document.getElementById('CAL');
    a.onchange = (ev) =>{
      console.log( a.value);} //Gets the CAL value of low,high,medium or naCal

    let b = document.getElementById('sev-lev-2');
    b.onchange = (ev) =>{
      console.log( b.value);} //Gets value of RBL as low, medium or high

    let c = document.getElementById('sev-lev-3');
    c.onchange = (ev) =>{
      console.log( c.value);} //Gets value of tooth loss as low, medium or high

    let d = document.getElementById('MPD');
    d.onchange = (ev) =>{
      console.log( d.value);} //Gets value of maximum pocket depth as low, medium or high
      
    let e = document.getElementById('type-bl');
    e.onchange = (ev) =>{
      console.log( e.value);} //Gets value of type of bone loss as low or high

    let f = document.getElementById('ST3a');
    {console.log(f.checked);}
    f.onchange = (ev) => 
    {console.log(f.checked);} //checks if Furcation is ticked in (true) or not

    let g = document.getElementById('ST3b');
    {console.log(g.checked);}
    g.onchange = (ev) => 
    {console.log(g.checked);} //checks if Moderate ridge defects is ticked in (true) or not

    let h = document.getElementById('ST4');
    {console.log(h.checked);}
    h.onchange = (ev) => 
    {console.log(h.checked);} //checks if Need complex rehab is ticked in (true) or not
```

I tried grouping some variables (ab) (ce) (fg), I am missing something to make these work, they always come out as undefined (when connecting a button to as an example console.log (ab), I tried multiple ways but are still stuck with this:

```
let ab //Gets value for CAL or RBL
    if (a === "low"|| b === "low") {ab= "low"}
    else if (a === "medium"|| b === "medium") {ab=== "medium"}
    else if (a === "hig"|| b === "high") {ab=== "high"}
    else {ab=="null"}

let fg;
if (f === "false"&& g === "false"){fg==="false"}
else {fg === "true"} ;

let ce;
if (c === "false"&& e === "false"){ce==="false"}
else {ce === "true"}
```

The other part of the problem is that when I get results for ab/ce/fg I would like to get the end result from a function,so that I can couple the function to a button click. I structured the function with or without the grouped variables but still could not get to work, the version with grouped variables is:

```
 function debug(){
    if (ab == "low" && d == "low" && ce == "low" && fg=="false" && h == "false" ) {console.log;{"I"}}
    else if (ab == "low" && d == "medium" && ce == "low" && fg=="false" && h == "false" ) {console.log ("II")}
    else if (ab == "medium" && (d == "low"|| d =="medium") && ce == "low" && fg=="false" && h == "false") {console.log ("II")}
    else if (ab == "medium" && ((c== "medium" || "high") ||(d=="high")||(e=="high")||(fg=="true"))) {console.log ("III")}
    else if (ab == "high" &&  (c!= "high" || h!="true")) {console.log ("III")}
    else if (ab=="high" && d== "high" && e=="high" && fg=="true" && h == "true") {console.log ("IV")}
    else {console.log("")}    
    }
```

The HTML for the forms is the following:

```
<div id="staging"> 
    <div id="severity">
    <h2>Severity (Site of greater loss)</h2>
        <div><label for="CAL">Clinical attachment level:</label>
            <select name="CAL" id="CAL" onclick="Severity()">
                <option value="">--Interdental CAL--</option>
                <option value="low">1-2mm</option>
                <option value="medium">3-4mm</option>
                <option value="high">&#62;5mm</option>
                <option value="naCal" >Not available</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="RBL"   ><label for="rx-bone-loss">Radiographic bone loss (% of root):</label>
            <select name="RBL" id="sev-lev-2" onclick="Severity2()">
                <option value="">--Select RBL %--</option>
                <option value="low"> &#60;15%</option>
                <option value="medium">15-33%</option>
                <option value="high">&#62;33%</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="TL"><label for="tooth-loss">Perio caused tooth loss:</label>
            <select name="tooth-loss" id="sev-lev-3">
                <option value="">--Or planned for extraction--</option>
                <option value="low"> None</option>
                <option value="medium">&#8804;4</option>
                <option value="high">&#8805;5</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Complexity">
        <h2>Complexity</h2>
        <p><label for="max-probing-depth">Max Probing Depth:</label>
            <select name="MPD" id="MPD">
                <option value="">--Max PD--</option>
                <option value="low"> &#8804;4mm</option>
                <option value="medium">&#8804;5mm</option>
                <option value="high">&#8805;6mm</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p><label for="type-bl">Type of bone loss:</label>
            <select name="type-bl" id="type-bl">
                <option value="">--Type--</option>
                <option value="low"> Mostly horizontal</option>
                <option value="high">Vertical &#8805;3mm </option>
            </select>

        </p>
        <form>  <p><b>Additional Information:</b></p>  
            <input type="checkbox" id="ST3a" value="ST3a"><label for="Furcation"> Furcation involvement cl II-III</label><br>  
            <input type="checkbox" id="ST3b" value="ST3b"><label for="Defect"> Moderate ridge defects</label><br>  
            <input type="checkbox" id="ST4" value="ST4"><label for="Rehab"> Need for complex rehabilitation</label><br>   
        </form>
    </div>
```

Additional problem:
First of all thanks for the answers, some of it I did understand, a great deal is too complicated for my level...
Now I got the form working on single selections, but when trying to select another value without refreshing the value seems to go to "undefined" and with a second try give an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
at a.onchange"

this code shows the error on one variable selection:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Perio Staging and Grading</title>
</head>
<body>
        <h2>Severity (Site of greater loss)</h2>
            <div><label for="CAL">Clinical attachment level:</label>
                <select name="CAL" id="CAL" >
                    <option value="">--Interdental CAL--</option>
                    <option value="low">1-2mm</option>
                    <option value="medium">3-4mm</option>
                    <option value="high">&#62;5mm</option>
                    <option value="naCal" >Not available</option>
                </select>
            </div>
</div>
    </div>
    <button id="debug">Submit</button>
    <div id="result">

    </div>

    <script>
    
    let a = document.getElementById('CAL');
    a.onchange = (ev) =>{
      a= (a.value);} //Gets the CAL value of low,high,medium or naCal
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: your assignments are coming out `undefined` because you aren't assigning to them: `fg==="false"` compares the values while `fg = "false"` assigns a value to `fg`. see: [What is the difference between the `=` and `==` operators and what is `===`? (Single, double, and triple equals)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871616/what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-operators-and-what-is-si)

Comment: Aside from that you stand to gain a lot of readability by organizing and streamlining your conditions.

Comment: Here is a quick working example which you can read over and see what you can glean: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pvn5hw81/3/). There are more built in APIs you can take advantage of such as direct access to [forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms), and the example makes use of [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation) to avoid setting multiple listeners.

Comment: Just a note on code style and indenting.  Indenting is much easier to read if you indent.  Since you put the end bracket at the end of the line in your code it makes it very hard to read as this is not the convention.  The end bracket should go on a line on it's own aligned with the section it is closing.  This makes the indenting pop and the code much easier to read.  I looked at your code for a long time without seeing all those closing brackets and being very confused

Comment: Thank you a lot for the help, I´ve seen your link and altough its too advanced for me I see that it works as intended. I managed to get mine also working but with a huge problem that i cant seem to solve, after selecting a value (lets say a becomes = low) if i select another value that should change a it goes to undetermined and an error appears if trying to select another value again