# If $variable = 0 not working

Tags: php, if-statement

```
if($_POST['user_admin'] = 0){ $acct_type = "a standard"; }
elseif($_POST['user_admin'] = 1){ $acct_type = "an administrator"; }
echo $acct_type;
echo $_POST['user_admin'];
```

Whether `$_POST['user_admin']` is 0 or 1, `$acct_type` still returns "an administrator" Why?

Comment: Replace `=` with `==` .... also look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [The 3 different equals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals)

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes you miss something after you've been staring at it for 10 minutes...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use "==" when comparing variables.

```
if($_POST['user_admin'] == 0){ $acct_type = "a standard"; }
elseif($_POST['user_admin'] == 1){ $acct_type = "an administrator"; }
echo $acct_type;
echo $_POST['user_admin'];
```

Answer (score 6):

It should be

```
if $variable == 0
```

Answer (score 2):

you are assigning value with = you should use $variable == 0 to compare the value

Answer (score 1):

You are on the first of [10 common PHP mistakes to avoid](http://www.ultramegatech.com/2009/11/10-common-php-mistakes-to-avoid/) :-)

```
   $_POST['user_admin'] = 0 
   $_POST['user_admin'] = 1
```

are both assignments. PHP evaluates whether the final assigned expression is true or false after assigning the value to $_POST['user_admin'] . So, the first one will evaluate to false since the assigned value is 0, and the second one will evaluate to true since the assigned value is 1.

As everyone pointed out, you have to use "==" instead of "=" for conditional statements.