# Active Records - Affected Rows always returning 1

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, rows-affected

I am trying to make a change password code using the active records. That works fine but I need to know whether the password was successfully changed or that the current password was actually wrong.

I am using affected rows to see how many records were affected. The value should be 1 or 0, 1 when the password has been successfully changed and 0 when it hasn't changed (that is entered current password was wrong.) The affected rows would never return more than 1 because the username is unique. So it should work the way I am approaching it.
But it doesn't seem to work, because the affected rows function is always returning 1.

Here are the Codes
**Controller:**

```
function changepass() {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'Password', 'required|matches[passconf]|min_length[6]|max_length[12]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
        //if not valid
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', validation_errors());
        redirect('profile');
    } else {
        //if valid
        $current = $this->input->post('current');
        $change = $this->input->post('pass');
        $id = $this->input->post('id');
        $flag = $this->profile_model->update_pass($current, $change, $id);
        if ($flag = true) {// If Successful
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $flag);
        } else { // If Unsuccessful
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Current Password is not valid');
        }
        redirect('profile');
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
function update_pass($current,$change,$id) {
  $data = array('pass'=>$change);
  $this->db->where('id',$id);
  $this->db->where('pass',$current);
  $this->db->update('users',$data);
  return ($this->db->affected_rows());
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense, ".. am trying to use affected rows to see if no. of affected rows are more than 1 then it is successfull else it has failed." 
It should be only one row will be affected.

Comment: I meant that if affected rows return a value more than 0 - which means rows have been affected.Rows affected couldnt be more than 1 because the username is unique. So the value of rows affected would be 0 or 1. If affected rows return 0, then username and password do not match, hence failed. If affected rows return 1 then the password was changed successfully.
But affected rows is always returning 1, even when the password change is not successful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The 3 different equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals)

Answer (score 2):

change your model like this

```
function update_pass($current, $change, $id) {
    $data = array('pass' => $change);
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->where('pass', $current);
    $this->db->update('users', $data);
    if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And change your controller if statement by adding '==' instead of '='

```
if($flag == TRUE)// If Successful
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $flag);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be its due to query caching.Turn of query caching for this particular query and try.

```
// Turn caching off for this one query 
  $this->db->cache_off();
  $data = array('pass'=>$change);
  $this->db->where('id',$id);
  $this->db->where('pass',$current);
  $this->db->update('users',$data);
  return ($this->db->affected_rows());
```

Comment: Well when i went to database.php in the config folder.
It was already this

$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;

I changed it to TRUE to see if anything happens. Nothing changed

Comment: turn profiler on: $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE); and copy the query and run in phpmyadmin

Comment: Well, i have checked that the active records produces the correct query.
Using the profiler on the controller i get the query -:
SELECT id,user,first_name,last_name,gender,type,dob,email  
FROM  `users` WHERE id =1

Comment: The above query is used by another function of the model which fetches the data of the the currently logged in user.
Don't think that the action of the script is to this function, because its not. 
The password changes in the database when the current password is correct, it shows the same thing on front when the current password is wrong but the password inside the database does not change.
The query generated by the Active Records is hence correct and that the submit button points to the right function

Comment: I figured it out the probem.
The If condition was like this - if($flag = TRUE)
Which should have been if($flag == TRUE)
Rather than evaluating the flag it was assigning true to flag.
Small unnoticeable but HUGE mistake -_-

Comment: @user2472998 yeah. I too missed that

Answer (score 0):

```
function update_pass($current, $change, $id)
{
  $data = array('pass'=>$change);
  $this->db->where('id',$id);
  $this->db->where('pass',$current);
  $this->db->update('users',$data);

  //comment the return
  //return ($this->db->affected_rows());

  // echo formatted last query
  echo '<pre>';
  echo $this->db->last_query();
  echo '</pre>';
  die();
 }
```

Are you sure you are supplying the right variables to do the update? Try this on you're model then test on you're `phpmyadmin` Or turn on `profiler` to see what queries are being run and what parameters are being passed on.

Or you can try

```
var_dump($this->db->affected_rows());
```

To see what is it returning.

Comment: UPDATE `users` SET `pass` = '123456' WHERE `id` =  '1' AND `pass` =  'qqq'

For current logged in user with id 1, current pass entered qqq and new pass 123456
The thing works for changing the pass. But i am not able to distinguish between the cases when pass changes and when it doesnt

Comment: is your `pass` hashed? or just plain text

Comment: Just Plain text. I am just trying without hashing it first to see that everything works. I will change to pass encryption when everything works, its like this now just to see if the values are changed successfully or not in the db.

Comment: I figured it out the probem.
The If condition was like this - if($flag = TRUE)
Which should have been if($flag == TRUE)
Rather than evaluating the flag it was assigning true to flag.
Small unnoticeable but HUGE mistake -_-

Answer (score -2):

try this code

```
function update_pass($current,$change,$id){
 $data = array('pass'=>$change);
 $this->db->where('id',$id);
 $this->db->where('pass',$current);
 $this->db->update('users',$data);
 $query = $this->db->affected_rows();
 if($query > 0){
    return true;
 }else{
    return false;
 }
}
```

Comment: This advice was provided by IshaS two and a half years earlier (and doesn't solve the issue).  Also, code-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.