# if condition holds true only for 0 when comparing it with string variable

Tags: php

The output of the code below is "fail" but if we pass `1 to $b as $b=1` then it will give the output as "pass". Can anybody tell me why this if condition holds true only for 0?

```
<?php 
      $a="abcd"; 
      $b=0; 
      if($a == $b)
      {
         echo "fail";
      } 
      else
      { 
         echo "pass";
      }
?>
```

Comment: Read all about [loose typing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) in comparisons

Comment: Yet again: PHP type judging with `==` operator.

Comment: [Read the PHP documentation on type comparisons](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) non-numeric strings will cast to integer zero when loosely compared.

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2063480/2536029

Comment: I like the fact that `$a = "123";` would "pass" because it evalutes to 123 and 123 != 0. PHP definitly favors integers.

Comment: @Christoph: if ($a = '123') will always pass ;)

Comment: @JimL `$a = "123";` <- do you often use semicolons in your ifs ?!

Comment: @Christoph: touchè, and here I was trying to be clever ^^

Answer (score 1):

That is because of PHP [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) with `==` operator. The full table is given [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Answer (score 1):

because you are comparing 2 variables of a different type, one of the 2 will be converted. In this case the string will be converted to an integer, which will be 0 for strings that do not start with a numeric value.

so `"abc" == 0` in PHP, to add a type check use `"abc" === 0`

Comment: Nothing says "thank you" like a freshly picked upvote. Also don't forget to mark an answer as accepted when your question is resolved.

Comment: where would I find that option??

Comment: It says vote up requires 15 reputation. Not working for me :(

Comment: there you go, upvoted ur question. marking an answer as correct should not require any rep i think.

Answer (score 0):

You're a victim of type juggling. Try using the [identical comparison operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), `===`, which also checks to make sure the types of variables are the same:

```
var_dump('abcd' === 0); // bool(false)
```

Comment: Non-empty strings don't evaluate to false.

Comment: Read the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Apologies; edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically. The type conversion does not take place when the comparison is === or !== as this involves comparing the type as well as the value.

```
if($a==$b) { 
    echo "fail";
} 
else { 
    echo "pass";
}
```

This will output `fail`.

But, if you use the identical comparison operator `===`, the type conversion does not take place:

```
if($a===$b) { 
    echo "fail";
} 
else { 
    echo "pass";
}
```

This will output pass.

For more details, refer to the [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) documentation in the PHP manual.