# Three equals signs in php comparison

Tags: php, operators

I was working on some code made by someone else and came across in if statement that looks like this 
    IF($res === true){
    do_something();}

This code is called many times and seems to be working.  What is it doing?

I know one equals is assignment and two is comparison.  What does the three equals sign operator do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to see it, is that `==` checks equality and `===` checks identicality. Equality will check the value, but identicality will check the variable type too.

Examples:

```
var_dump('true' == true); // bool(true)
var_dump('true' === true); // bool(false)
```

Comment: Your examples are only going to add to the confusion for someone already having difficulty with this subject. Any non-empty string is boolean true but to use 'true' as the example string is just muddying the water.

Comment: Since we're explaining the difference between something being equal and something being identical, using a string called true fits perfectly. Using something other than true would just serve to confuse a user even more as they're not even remotely similar.

Answer (score 1):

This is the "identical" operator.  They'll need to be exactly the same to pass the condition.

[The 3 different equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals)

Answer (score 1):

Three === means that result has to be identical. Worded it wrong first time :)

Comment: I don't understand why did someone down vote this? its correct. 3 = signs means that it has to be IDENTICAL. and that is what I wrote I don't see the problem

Comment: PHP doesn't have 'datatype' nor is it an object comparison, it's actually variable type. It will work with objects, somewhat.

Comment: OK maybe I didn't word it correctly but I was trying to say exact same thing that you said it needs to be IDENTICAL.

Comment: It was just to get you to change the definition, confusion can be caused by incorrect definition.

Comment: I can appreciate that :).. Good choice ! :)