# php password system gives error

Tags: php

I'm practicing some php and I am creating this password system.
my code doesn't work. anyone notices a mistake?
I think it's just a stupid fault, but i can't seem to find it.

```
<?php
$passwords = array("name1"   =>"pass1", 
                   "name2"   =>"pass2");

if ($password = $passwords[$username]){
setcookie("username", $username, time()+1200);
echo "<H2>Access granted.</H2>";
}
else{
    setcookie("username", "", time()-3600);
    echo "<H2>Invalid user name or password: access denied.</H2>";
}
?>
```

thanks everyone!
my stupid fault was that i used = instead of == to check if $password is equal to $passwords[$username]

Comment: Single = in your if() should be ==

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$passwords = array("name1"   =>"pass1","name2"   =>"pass2");
if ($password == $passwords[$username]){
 setcookie("username", $username, time()+1200);
 echo "<H2>Access granted.</H2>";
}
else{
    setcookie("username", "", time()-3600);
    echo "<H2>Invalid user name or password: access denied.</H2>";
}
?>
```

You have forgot = in this row:

```
  if ($password == $passwords[$username]){
```

If you use this '=' you define this variable. But '==' it checks the variable!

Comment: ah ofcourse, stupid mistake. thank you!

Comment: @Goosebumbs also check for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals

Comment: thanks, I know the difference, I just went over it to quickly i guess. thanks everyone for answering this quickly by the way!

Answer (score 2):

You are doing an assignment instead of comparison on your `if` statement.

Should be like

```
if ($password == $passwords[$username]){
```

Note the `==` instead of `=`

Comment: **Am I getting downvotes since I answered first ?**

Comment: Ofcourse me too.someone is playing I think

Comment: yes, don't know whats happening. I think some one is playing with us.

Comment: I don't get it also. please know that I thank you very much for answering this quickly. they downvoted my question also so it wasn't me myself.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Double equal` for the comparision.If you give single equal the it will only assign the right side variable to left side variable,and that to,the assigning will return always `true`

```
if ($password == $passwords[$username]){
```

Comment: what's going on..Me and even @Shankar getting downs even we are the first

Answer (score 0):

Use if like this:

```
if ($password == $passwords[$username]){
//code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using assignment operator(=) instead of equality operator(==). Replace with

```
if ($password == $passwords[$username])
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
if ($password == $passwords[$username])
```

Use == instead of = in if statement.

Comment: yes, don't know whats happening. I think some one is playing with us.