# why does this equal false in php

Tags: php

Why does this print false. Is it because month is string and true is boolean?

```
$month = "string";
if ($month === true) {
    echo "true";
} else {
   echo "false";
}
```

Comment: Is $month defined at all?

Comment: What else you expect ?

Comment: Read the Friendly Manual - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php - it's fairly explicit in its explanation

Answer (score 2):

`===` is comparison operator for value **and** type, so `$month` have to be a `boolean` (and also `true`, of course). Is it?

You should use `$month == true` (that will compare only value, regardless of type) or simply `if($month)` (as don't exist months that could be 0)

Answer (score 1):

When using '===' you are doing a comparison by value AND by type. Since `$month = 'string';` is obviously of type string, it doesn't equal boolean `true`, and so the expression evaluates to false.

To make it output "true", replace the "===" operator with "=="

Here's a link to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals) here on SO which sums it up nicely

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

== is used to compare, but using === (note the extra '=' sign) will also check the type of data.
Because $month contains a string, and you are comparing it with a boolean, it will return false.

When you'd be using ==, it would return true.

Answer (score 0):

at condition time if u have not declared the $month variable. then $month will be undefined and '===' true will returns false always.

Comment: Any test against $month will return false except `is_null()` which will give an `E_NOTICE` and return true, and `empty()` will return true

Comment: Ignore the "E_NOTICE" part of my comment above, that test will trigger an `E_NOTICE` if run on an undeclared variable.