# What does false mean in... if ($var !== false)

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, exec, var

Take this example, does this load the echo if say for example php exec is enabled and I can run this command: `/etc/init.d/mysql restart` or would I need to set `!== false` to `!== true`?

```
$var = exec('/etc/init.d/mysql restart');

if ($var !== false) {
   echo "php exec is enabled";
}
```

Basically what I am trying to do is, restart mysql from php if this function is enabled on the server

```
$var = exec('/etc/init.d/mysql restart');

if ($var !== false) {
   exec('/etc/init.d/mysql restart');
   echo "php exec is enabled and restart mysql";
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2063500/4022234 Read this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you are checking function  it will gives you error

```
$var = exec(); // need to pass an argument
```

for check a function exist or not try

```
if(function_exists('exec')) {
    echo "php exec is enabled";
}
```

also according to updated you need to pass retrun argument to function to check returning values

```
exec('/etc/init.d/mysql restart', $output, $return);
// Return will return non-zero upon an error
if (!$return) {
   echo "php exec is enabled";
}
```

For more info :- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php