# Looping flat array with while() never starts -- first element is 0

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop, conditional-statements

When I run the code given below, it outputs nothing in the browser.
What Am I doing wrong? Please help.

```
$ages = [0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20];

while ($age = current($ages)) {
    echo $age . ",";
    next($ages);
}
```

Comment: Hint: what does `current($ages)` return in the first iteration?

Comment: Related Javascript page: [Why does the while loop stop when condition check variable becomes 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39974993/2943403)

Comment: A similar PHP fail on a zero value in a loop: [strpos of 0 breaking while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28591826/2943403)

Answer (score 5):

The first test made is `while (0)`, because the first value is 0. So, the loop is never executed.

You can use a [`foreach()`](https://www.php.net/foreach) loop instead

```
$ages = [0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20];
foreach ($ages as $age) {
    echo $age . ',';
}
```

Or just [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/implode) for a better result (because it will not have a trailing `,`).

```
echo implode(',', $ages);
```

Answer (score 5):

To fix your current problem, when you use `current($ages)` in the first iteration of the loop, this will return the first item in the list - which is 0.  As the while loop only continues whilst the value is not false (which 0 also counts) the loop will not be run, so...

```
while(($age = current($ages)) !== false){
    echo $age.",";
    next($ages);
}
```

alternatively, use a `foreach` loop...

```
foreach ( $ages as $age)    {
    echo $age.",";
}
```