# PHP $_GET is set to a specific string

Tags: php

I am looking to expand upon my PHP Knowledge, and have done some research on the internet. What I am trying to do is execute some code when a variable is set in the URL.

```
    if($_GET['variable']) && $_GET['variable'] = "something") {
        echo "Do This.";
    }
```

However, the code will still run regardless what `variable` is equal to, as long as it is set. How would I go about achieving mygoal?

Comment: double equals or triple instead of one in the condition ?

Comment: 1) You should get a few errors for this code 2) maybe try `isset()` 3) Learn the difference between all three equal signs

Comment: because it's always true `=` which is an assigment; compare `==` against something.

Comment: @Fred-ii- The assignment is outside of the if statement: `if($_GET['variable'])` :)

Comment: @Rizier123 then the question's a dupe mix of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index - new canonical required? ;-)

Comment: *assigment* - groan, I forgot the "n" --- "assignment". There.

Answer (score 0):

This should works :

```
if(isset($_GET['variable']) && $_GET['variable'] == "something") {
    echo "Do This.";
}
```

Comment: some added tid bits of information as to why it should work and why the OP's code failed in the first place, would be lovely. Enlighten everyone, and for future visitors.