# My PHP script looks like it should work, so why doesn't it?

Tags: php

I'm working on a guestbook for my website. What I have right now is a basic HTML form:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
  Name: <input type="text" value="Julian Davis" name="name"readonly><br>
  E-mail (Not published) <input type="text" name="email"><br>
  Message: <input name="message" rows="5" cols="40"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

(the name field being read-only is part of the gag). It uses HTTP POST to send the results to submit.php, which looks like this:

```
<?php

if strlen($_POST["message"]) = 0 {
  echo "You didn\'t type a message. Don't you want people to hear 
  what you have to say?";
}

else if strlen($_POST["message"]) > 499 {
  echo "Messages are limited to 500 characters. Try again.";
}

else{
  echo "Your response has been received. Cheers!";
}
?>
```

I'm planning to add some SQL queries to aggregate the responses, but first I want this script to not return a blank page.

I haven't written any forms or used POST before (plus, I'm a little shaky on my elseifs), so it's probably some silly syntax thing, but I've looked the script up and down, and I can't see anything wrong with it.

(Also, if anyone has any tips for how to make this form secure, perhaps a CAPTCHA, please let me know!)

Comment: you're assigning in your first conditional statement.

Comment: You're missing parentheses around the condition in `if`.

Comment: Aren't you getting syntax errors from the code?

Comment: Not using this, obviously http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @Dagon, this isn't a duplicate of that one, but a mundane question I guess.

Comment: @Barmar, No, I'm not using an IDE, I'm just editing code in vim on my server and then loading the page on my local browser.

Comment: I didn't mean an error from the IDE, I meant an error message from PHP when you try to load the page.

Comment: `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', true);`. I'm seriously going to put this on a t-shirt and try to spread the message. maybe put it on a placard and bring it to football games.

Comment: This is a syntax error-based type of question and falls under quite a few duplicates, far as I'm concerned. The only choice we have, is to vote accordingly.

Comment: Invalid input syntax also for "message".

Comment: @J.Davis Did you have a look at my answer? Do you think that helps you?

Comment: @Darragh that may be the most useful PHP command I have seen all day.

Answer (score 8):

**Many issues:**

1. All your [`if`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) statements should have `( ... )` in them, the whole syntax is wrong! Learn PHP well.

   ```
   if (expr)
     statement
   ```
2. And the first one should have `==` instead of `=`.

   There are lot of questions that answer this. See [The 3 different equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals).

   - The `=` is assignment operator. This means, the left side variable gets assigned a new value.
   - The `==` is what you need, which is a comparison operator. Checks whether left side and right side are equal.
   - The `===` is strict comparison operator, which checks both the value and type of the data.
3. Also better to use [`elseif`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) instead of `else if`.

   As said in the comments, *Note that elseif and else if will only be considered exactly the same when using curly brackets as in the above example. When using a colon to define your if/elseif conditions, you must not separate else if into two words, or PHP will fail with a parse error."*

**Corrected Code:**

```
<?php
    if (strlen($_POST["message"]) == 0) {
        echo "You didn\'t type a message. Don't you want people to hear what you have to say?";
    }

    elseif (strlen($_POST["message"]) > 499) {
        echo "Messages are limited to 500 characters. Try again.";
    }

    else {
        echo "Your response has been received. Cheers!";
    }
?>
```

Plus, your input syntax is invalid

```
<input name="message" rows="5" cols="40">
```

This type of syntax is for `<textarea>`.  i.e.:

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
```

The syntax is:

```
<input type="text" name="input_name" maxlength="4" size="4">
```

If you absolutely want to have that `<input />` larger than the others, you will need to resort to using CSS.

Comment: *"Also better to use elseif instead of else if"* - http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php *"Note: Note that elseif and else if will only be considered exactly the same when using curly brackets as in the above example. When using a colon to define your if/elseif conditions, you must not separate else if into two words, or PHP will fail with a parse error."*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Well, that's fine. We **are** using curly braces here, right? And moreover, I am asking the OP to use `elseif` only.

Comment: They sure are. that was just a sidenote for future visitors. However,  *"And the first one should have `==` instead of `=`"* adding the fact that they are assigning rather than comparing, would improve the answer, should my comment happen to disappear about that ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- See my updated previous comment and answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Updated buddy.

Comment: Very nicely done, *cheers*

Comment: Thought I'd put in my own "2 cents", after studying the OP's code a bit more closely. Something else looked out of whack. However, it's hard to say if OP wanted a bigger input than the others or not, which is why I added a note about using CSS and you removed.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I edited it, but accidentally removed it.

Comment: It's ok. I probably stood at being wrong. I myself sometimes do like to use larger buttons for certain inputs. But in this case, it's pretty clear that they should/want to use a `<textarea>`, given "message". It would hard to write out a long message for an input. *YIPES!*