# why break; dosn't work when i press esc?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, break, do-while

everything's work fine but at the end of this code i write else if statement to exit the program when user press esc key but when user press that key nothing's happen !!!! what's my mistake ??? i write this code in visual studio 2013.

```
/***************************************************\
* This program imagery dice rolling                 *
* Write by : saeid asaadian                         *
* Create date : 11 - 14 - 2015                      *
* Version : 1.0                                     *
\***************************************************/
#include <iostream>
#include "conio.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#define random(x)(rand()%x)
#define randomize()(srand(time(0)))
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Please press ENTER to roll the dice and press ESC for exit .";
    do
    {
        char ch = getchar();
        if (ch = 13)
        {
            system("cls");
            randomize();
            switch (random(6) + 1)
            {
            case 1:
                cout << "The dice is 1";
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "The dice is 2";
                break;
            case 3:
                cout <<"The dice is 3";
                break;
            case 4:
                cout << "The dice is 4";
                break;
            case 5:
                cout << "The dice is 5";
                break;
            default:
                cout << "The dice is 6";
            } //end of switch
        }  //end of if
        else 
        if (ch = 27)
            break;
    } while (1);   //end of do.while
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't call `srand` inside a loop, especially when you use `time` to get the seed. Call it *once* only, at the beginning of the program.

Comment: Why aren't you stepping through your code to find out?

Comment: This is for PHP, but completely applicable for your specific problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals

Comment: As for your problem, are you sure that the terminal/console will send the escape "character" to your program to read with `getchar`? Also, don't use the ["magic number"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) `13` for a carriage return, use the proper `'\r'` character. By the way, not all platforms send a carriage return for for newlines, not to mention that some functions *translate* the newline sequence so you only get the newline character `'\n'`.

Comment: Finally, if you're programming C++, why are you using the C-function `getchar`?

Comment: im  new in c++ and i write this for practis

Comment: There's also a fair amount of redundancy in using a `switch` in your code like that. You can just use `cout << "The dice is " << random(6) + 1;` intstead of the whole `switch (random(6) + 1) { //... }` thing you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

`=` is assignment in C++, it does not check equality.

Change your last if statement to `if (ch == 27)`.
EDIT: Change all of them to use ==

Comment: Your question was asking why the last if statement doesn't work, and I told you why.  This isn't CodeReview.  Poor programming practices weren't part of the question.

Comment: when i change = to == when i press enter the cursor just go to next line

Comment: Did you change `char = getchar();` as well?  Because if you did, that's wrong.  Please just learn the difference between `=` and `==`.