# Why aren't my conditional statements working in php?

Tags: php, function, logic

This code will run right out of the box, the issue is that it keeps hittign the "pvp" cconditional statement rather than the "account_name" statement... and clearly gw2action is "account_name"....

Comment: Use == for checking equality, not =

Answer (score 1):

Use `==` when comparing values, one `=` is assignment and `==` is is used to compare the value of the variable on the left to the string in this case on the right.

So `if($gw2action = "pvp")` is actually assigning the value of pvp to $gw2action, it should be `if($gw2action == "pvp")` etc

Answer (score 0):

You are using the assign operator inside an elseif condition. It always returns a true, I think. You have `=` the assignment operator, `==` the 'equal' comparison operator and `===` the 'identical' comparison operator.

this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals) may help.