# How exactly is null defined in PHP?

Tags: php

How come `null` which is a predefined value in PHP equal to `0` and less than `-1` at the same time?
Refer to code below:

```
<?php
var_dump(null == 0); // evaluates to true
var_dump(null < -1); // this also evaluates to true
?>
```

Comment: What is your use case for this?

Comment: I encountered `null` value for some variable while debugging a numeric comparison code block. It compares the same variable at two places with different conditions: `if ($var == 0) { .. some code .. } ... if ($var < -1) { .. some other code ..}` Where, developer expected control to enter only one of these two blocks, but ended up executing both. And, `null` is a valid value for that variable.

Comment: You can solve the first one by using a value & type comparison - `var_dump(null === 0); // returns false`.

Comment: Yes @Darren, that's what I did. My question is, when using `==` operator, why the same predefined value evaluates to `true` for such a not-possible-mathematically comparison? Isn't that a constant and supposed to evaluate to true for only and only one value?

Comment: Convert it to an `int` before you do your comparisons then -> `var_dump( (int) null == 0 );` **and** `var_dump( (int) null < -1 );` - only 1 will return true.

Comment: Yeah, that fixes the problem in code. But the question is really about inconsistent comparison in PHP (and not about how to fix it in code).

Comment: [The 3 different equals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**it not the value of null which is giving you the results its the dynamic conversion happing during comparision**

For the php manual

For various types, comparison is done according to the following table (in order).

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

[image]

You can see that if Operand 1 is bool or null and Operand 2 is anything than convert the side to bool applies, and also 0 is false in php, also in PHP treats null ,false, 0, and the empty string as equal. so

```
var_dump(null == 0);
```

is like `var_dump(false == false);` which evaluates to **true**

and `var_dump(null < -1)` is like `var_dump(false < true)` which is **again true**

hence you are getting these results

Comment: just to elaborate other that zero all numbers are treated as true so -1 is also true

Comment: That makes more sense! But if I run following code, I see a mix of first two lines from that table:

`<?php
echo (bool)null;
echo "\n";
echo (bool)-1;
echo "\n";

var_dump( null == 0);
var_dump( null < -1);

?>`

The output is:
`
-- empty line here --
1
bool(true)
bool(true)
`

Comment: In addition to Dinkar's answer, you may want to refer to "Loose comparisons with ==" table at http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: It's such pieces of code that make you dig more into PHP. :D