# Three file types saving as one?

Tags: php, file, types, upload, web

Hi I have a website that is able to upload three types of files, however when I upload, not matter which type is uploaded they all turn into .aiff files. Suuuper lame. where did i go wrong with this code? :/ thanks so much. (some of this code was made by another person and modified)

```
// Types of files that are acceptiable for uploading. Keep the array structure.
$allow_types=array("wav","mp3","aiff");

// Function to get the extension a file.
function get_ext($key) { 
    $key=strtolower(substr(strrchr($key, "."), 1));
    $key=str_replace("wav","mp3","aiff",$key);
    return $key;
}

    //Tally the size of all the files uploaded, check if it's over the ammount. 
    If(array_sum($_FILES['file']['size']) > $max_combined_size*1024) {

        $error.="<b>FAILED:</b> All Files <b>REASON:</b> Combined file size is to large.<br />";

    // Loop though, verify and upload files.
    } Else {
print $key; 
        // Loop through all the files.
        For($i=0; $i <= $file_uploads-1; $i++) {

            // If a file actually exists in this key
            If($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]) {

                //Get the file extension
                $file_ext[$i]=get_ext($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);

                // Randomize file names
                If($unique_name){

                if($key=1){
                $file_name[$i]=1;
                while(1){
                $file_name[$i] =$file_name[$i]+1;
                if (!file_exists("uploads/$file_name[$i].aiff")){ break;}
                }}

                elseif($key=2){
                $file_name[$i]=1;
                while(1){
                $file_name[$i] =$file_name[$i]+1;
                if (!file_exists("uploads/$file_name[$i].mp3")){ break;}
                }}
                elseif($key=3){
                $file_name[$i]=1;
                while(1){
                $file_name[$i] =$file_name[$i]+1;
                if (!file_exists("uploads/$file_name[$i].wav")){ break;}
                }}

                } Else {
                    $file_name[$i]=cln_file_name($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);
                }

                // Check for blank file name
                If(str_replace(" ", "", $file_name[$i])=="") {

                    $error.= "<b>FAILED:</b> ".$_FILES['file']['name'][$i]." <b>REASON:</b> Blank file name detected.<br />";

                //Check if the file type uploaded is a valid file type. 
                }   ElseIf(!in_array($file_ext[$i], $allow_types)) {

                    $error.= "<b>FAILED:</b> ".$_FILES['file']['name'][$i]." <b>REASON:</b> Invalide file type.<br />";

                //Check the size of each file
                } Elseif($_FILES['file']['size'][$i] > ($max_file_size*1024)) {

                    $error.= "<b>FAILED:</b> ".$_FILES['file']['name'][$i]." <b>REASON:</b> File to large.<br />";

                // Check if the file already exists on the server..
                } Elseif(file_exists($folder.$file_name[$i].".".$file_ext[$i])) {

                    $error.= "<b>FAILED:</b> ".$_FILES['file']['name'][$i]." <b>REASON:</b> File already exists.<br />";

                } Else {

                    If(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i],$folder.$file_name[$i].".".$file_ext[$i])) {

                        $success.="<b>SUCCESS:</b> ".$_FILES['file']['name'][$i]."<br />";


                    } Else {
                        $error.="<b>FAILED:</b> ".$_FILES['file']['name'][$i]." <b>REASON:</b> General upload failure.<br />";
                    }

                }

            } // If Files

        } // For

    } // Else Total Size

    If(($error=="") AND ($success=="")) {
        $error.="<b>FAILED:</b> No files selected<br />";
    }

    $display_message=$success.$error;

} // $_POST AND !$password_form

/*
```

Comment: Sorry, could you please shorten your code to the _relevant_ parts? No one is going through that wall of code.

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals - clue: `if($key=x)`

Comment: can you remove the comment lines from the question

Comment: aren't you replacing the extensions? `$key=str_replace("wav","mp3","aiff",$key);`

Comment: shortened my code to the important parts sorry

Comment: I think there is an error in your function to get the extension. Try to use this code to obtain file extension:
$file_ext[$i] = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

Comment: Look, I'll show it to you once again `if($key=x)` what does that read as? It's not comparing here, it's "assigning". Same for all the other ones.

Comment: oh my you are a genius. Fixed!! thank you