# PHP elseif statement defaults to first block

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying the following elseif statement to call the correct code based on a POST from the previous page and it has been defaulting to using only the first block of code i am aware that this might not be the best way to carry out the code in this situation so i'd like to ask if anyone has a more efficient way of doing this THANKS

```
elseif ($toyota="on"){
$query = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE name LIKE '%toyota%'";
}
elseif ($bmw="on"){
$query = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE name LIKE '%Bmw%'";
}
elseif ($subaru="on"){
$query = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE name LIKE '%Subaru%'";
}
elseif ($mitsubishi="on"){
$query = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE name LIKE '%Mitsubi%'";
}
elseif ($nissan="on"){
$query = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE name LIKE '%Nissan%'";
}
elseif ($mazda="on"){
$query = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE name LIKE '%Mazda%'";
}
elseif ($chrysler="on"){
$query = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE name LIKE '%Chrysler%'";
}
```

Forgot to mention,the post from html comes like 
"toyota=on", "bmw=on" and so on

Comment: you need to use `==` in the tests - not `=`

Comment: hi, please read the above edit thank you

Comment: reading your edit is pointless. that has nothing to do with the problem. you need to learn the difference between `==` and `=`...

Comment: the '=' is already part of the post which it just needs to be checked for in php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The 3 different equals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$cars = array('toyota', 'bmw', 'nissan');

foreach ($cars as $car) {
    if (!isset($_POST[$car]) || $_POST[$car] != 'on') {
         continue;
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE name LIKE '%$car%'";
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is difference between = and ==.

= assigns value, whereas == compares value.

replace all your = with ==

```
($toyota=="on"){
```

There is much better way to do that instead of using so many if else blocks. try using a varibale in the query based on the input.

Answer (score 0):

A single `=` will set a value whereas a double `==` will test for equality

```
elseif ($toyota=="on"){
$query = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE name LIKE '%toyota%'";
}
elseif ($bmw=="on"){
$query = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE name LIKE '%Bmw%'";
}
elseif ($subaru=="on"){
$query = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE name LIKE '%Subaru%'";
}
elseif ($mitsubishi=="on"){
$query = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE name LIKE '%Mitsubi%'";
}
elseif ($nissan=="on"){
$query = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE name LIKE '%Nissan%'";
}
elseif ($mazda=="on"){
$query = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE name LIKE '%Mazda%'";
}
elseif ($chrysler=="on"){
$query = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE name LIKE '%Chrysler%'";
}
```