# isset $_GET not showing right info

Tags: php, get, isset

My code below doesnt work

```
<?php 
//Laat homepage zien als het leeg is
if(!isset($_GET['page']))
{
include 'includes/view/homepage.php';
echo $index;
}
elseif(empty($_GET["page"]))
{
include 'includes/view/homepage.php';
echo $index;
}
//Laat uitleg zien van hypixel api
elseif(isset($_GET['page']) === "hypixel")
{
include 'includes/view/hypixelapi.php';
echo $index;
}
//Laat errors zien die je kan krijgen
elseif(isset($_GET['page']) === "errors")
{
include 'includes/view/errors.php';
echo $index;
}
//Laat player api uitleg zien
elseif(isset($_GET['page']) === "player")
{
include 'includes/view/playerapi.php';
echo $index;
}
//Laat server api uitleg zien
elseif(isset($_GET['page']) === "server")
{
include 'includes/view/serverapi.php';
echo $index;
}
//Laat error 404 zien als het fout is
else
{
include 'includes/errors/404.php';
echo $index;
}
?>
```

When i go to

> localhost/directory/ or localhost/directory/?page=

It shows the homepage
but when i go to

> localhost/directory/?page=errors or localhost/directory/?page=hypixel

It shows the 404 page

Comment: `isset` return `bool`. You should compare this way: `elseif ($_GET['page'] === "hypixel")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll using `isset()` function to assign variables which should not be the case:

```
isset($_GET['page']) === "player"
```

This will return `true` if `$_GET['page']` is set.

As from the literal meaning `isset()` means variable is set. It's a `BOOL` function, which means that it can only return `true` when set and `false` when not set/ empty.

Thus, your code should be:

```
$_GET['page'] == "player"
```

`==` is for comparison, while `===` is whether it's identical, more information at [The 3 different equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals).

More information on `isset()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing `isset($_GET['page'])`to `"value"`. `isset` returns true/false, so you want to compare `$_GET['page']` variable to `"value"`, not if it is set.

So your `elseif` statement should look like this:

```
elseif($_GET['page'] === "hypixel")
{
include 'includes/view/hypixelapi.php';
echo $index;
}
```