# Go to page from text input

Tags: php

I am trying to make a simple form that when certain text is entered it will redirect to another page.

Form:

```
<form action="goto.php" method="post">
Destination: <input type="text" name="destination">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

I am unsure of how to set up  `goto.php` to achieve the desired result.  I basically want something like the following:

```
<?php 
if ($_POST["destination"]="mail" ) {
    header( 'Location: /mail/' );
} elseif ($_POST["destination"]="forms") {
    header( 'Location: /forms/' );
} else {
    echo "Invalid";
}
?>
```

However, this doesn't work because the way `header();` works makes the form go to `/mail/` no matter what text is entered.  How can I resolve this to achieve my desired result?

Comment: You're not comparing, you're assigning. Use `==` not `=`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're **assigning** `'mail'` to `$_POST["destination"]` which returns true so the `if` is valid

Do this instead:

```
<?php 
if ($_POST["destination"] =="mail" ) {//Note the ==
    header( 'Location: /mail/' );
} elseif ($_POST["destination"]=="forms") { //Note the ==
    header( 'Location: /forms/' );
} else {
    echo "Invalid";
}
?>
```

See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for more on Comparison Operators

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like that. In your condition you just attribute the destination and you make only one header(...)

```
<?php 
if ($_POST["destination"] === "mail" ) {
    $destination = '/mail/';
} elseif ($_POST["destination"] === "forms") {
    $destination = '/forms/';
} else {
    echo "Invalid";
    return;
}
header( 'Location: ' . $destination );
?>
```