# What does the !function() do?

Tags: php

I was looking up true/false bool conditions from the php manual and I thought this should echo a false, but it echos a true instead.  So what does the `!call()` truly do?  Is it saying that the function is just working?

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

```
<?php
    $true=0; //false

    function call($true)
    {
        if ($true =1){
            return TRUE;

        }
        if ($true =0){
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    if(call()) { 
        echo "true";
    }

    if(!call()) // or if(!call()) {
        echo "false";
    }

    if($true) { 
        echo "<br>true";
    }

    if(!$true)  {
        echo "<br>false";
    }
?>
```

Output:

```
true

false
```

Comment: See [The 3 different equals](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2063480) for your if statements in your function (And https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions as a little trick). Note that you never pass your variable to the function. Also see [What does this symbol mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3737139) for the `!` symbol.

Comment: From your comment, I see my error, totally missed the  $true ==.

Comment: You're also not passing your variable to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function call() returns `true` or `false`. `!call()` would simply indicate the scenario where the return value of this function is false.

Personally I like to set functions with Boolean return values, when called, equal to a variable, so I would definitely write:

```
$val = call();

if(!$val) {}
```

In your case, if you wanted to cut code to a minimum, you could write

```
echo call() ? "true" : "false";
```

to replace these lines:

```
if(call())
{ 
    echo "true";
}

if(!call()) // or if(!call())
{
    echo "false";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`!` is the logic operator `not`. Let's say you defined a var:

```
$myVar = true ;
var_dump( !$myVar); // will echo false
```

Your call() function will return `true` or `false`. So `!cal();` will return the opposite, `false` or `true`.

Have a look at the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).