# Some rows aren't counted in a foreach loop

Tags: php

I get price from database with 9xx items.
I add this on show items page. Using Foreach $rows=$row. vprice is my sellingprice and dprice is my dealerprice

```
$commisionrate = 30;
$commisionfee  = 100;
$fee  = $row['dprice'] + $commisionfee;//+100
$x = $row['dprice'];
$y = $x * $commisionrate / 100;
$z = $x + $y;
$rate = $z;//(100*30%)+100
if (($rate > $row['vprice']) && ($fee < $row['vprice'])){
    echo $fee;
}elseif (($fee > $row['vprice']) && ($rate < $row['vprice'])){
    echo $rate;
}elseif ($row['dprice']=$row['vprice']){
    echo $row['dprice'];
}
```

when I recheck all, I found that few items of `$row['dprice']` is not counted and still show by old price. Example that is false: I found vprice is 188 with 80 dprice after calculate should be 104 but not changing with still stay on 80.

Comment: show some outputs...

Comment: May also want to add the query that pulls these values from the database,  Sounds silly, but lets make sure you're actually pulling all the rows you think you're pulling

Comment: `$row['dprice']=$row['vprice']` is `$row['dprice'] == $row['vprice']`

Comment: possible duplicate of [The 3 different equals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals)

Comment: @RamansathiyaNarayanan i get all the output then i count to them.

Comment: if u want to compare the values you have to use "doubleequalto(==)" and if u want to assign a value to a variable use "singleequalto(=)", got it

Comment: @EatPeanutButter i get all the values before i count. And i tried for severel time and step it one by one also same.

Comment: @u_mulder same answer before that i using ==. Then i change = to more clear.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thank for the advise. Will try for that.

Comment: @RamansathiyaNarayanan for the double equal i think is not use for me. I deleted for dprice = vprice also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$commisionrate = 30;
$commisionfee  = 100;
$fee  = $row['dprice'] + $commisionfee;//+100
$x = $row['dprice'];
$y = $x * $commisionrate / 100;
$rate = $x + $y;

// You don't need to put nested brackets, it very simple condition    
if ($rate > $row['vprice'] && $fee < $row['vprice']){
    echo "fee: " . $fee; //add some hint words, so you know which condition fires

// You don't need to put nested brackets, it very simple condition
} elseif ($fee > $row['vprice'] && $rate < $row['vprice']) {
    echo "rate: " . echo $rate;

// USE double `==`, because when single `=` used, the condition always returns true and you're confused by your result
} elseif ($row['dprice'] == $row['vprice']) { 
    echo "row[\'dprice\']: " . $row['dprice'];

// add last else
} else {
   // this is helpful for debugging of your possible output, regardless you are awaiting some output here
}
```

Comment: Hi. Im not confuse for the result. I only forget to add 1 more condition that if rate and fee is lower than vprice then will choose to use rate price.