# PHP - What is this if statement meaning?

Tags: php

I use PHP around 3 months  see many syntax.
but cannot understand what is this mean.

```
if($foo = 'somevalue') //or if($foo = $somevalue)
{

}
```

I see only if($foo)  this mean if($foo == TRUE). or if($foo ==,>,< somevalue)
but in this case, if$foo hold some value???

Comment: In your code its just an assignment of variable. The If condition checks for the comparison..

Comment: so...it same as assignment outside if statement right?

Comment: @doflamingo, Yes...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The 3 different equals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals)

Comment: duplicate?  I know operator already.  but I just don't know the " = "  in "if"

Comment: It is the same equals..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just simultaneously **assigning** a value to `$foo` and evaluating it in the `if` statement. So if the value of `$foo` corresponds to `false`, then code inside the `if` statement would not execute. As an example:

```
if ($foo = 12) { // foo's value is now 12
    // code here would execute
}
echo $foo; // 12

if ($foo = 0) { // foo's value is now 0
    // would not execute
}
echo $foo; // 0
```

Answer (score 2):

as many will say `=` assigns the value. however this is useful in if statements aswell

the if statement `if($foo = 'somevalue')` is generally bad because [it will always evaluate to true](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting). however `if($foo = $somevalue)` is somewhat a bit better because it's similar to what you see when checking the results of a database query, for instance with

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT Name FROM City LIMIT 10"))
```

if `$mysqli->query` is successful in running the if statement evaluates to true because the succesful retunr result of the function is not considered FALSE and inside your if statement you can expect that `$result` to be usable for other `mysqli_*` function.

however if `$mysqli->query` is not successful it'll return false and the if statement evaluates to false and you can set up an else statement to output an error. you will get the same result if you did

```
$somevalue = $mysqli->query("SELECT Name FROM City LIMIT 10")
if($foo = $somevalue)
```

but you kinda waste time doing an extra line like this when you can just skip `$somevalue` all together

Answer (score 0):

This `if` statement will simply either

- return true and assign the string `somevalue` to `$foo`
- return false because `somevalue` cannot be assigned to `$foo`

In a lot of cases, this is a mistake in the writing of that `if` statment, where someone might want to check if the value of `$foo` is the string `somevalue`.

To properly evaluate that, one would want the following

```
if ($foo == 'somevalue') //$somevalue
```

Where `=` would assign a new value, `==` compares two values. see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-php-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comp) for more information on that.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a single = sign, it signifies assignment operator. i.e The if condition will always return true.

```
$a = 2;
if ($a = 3) {
    echo "True";
} else {
    echo "False";
}

//Output: True
```

Whereas, if you use logical operator ==, it will compare the two values and return boolean true/false.

```
$a = 2;
if ($a == 3) {
    echo "True";
} else {
    echo "False";
}

//Output: False
```

Comment: `The if condition will always return true.` is not true. https://eval.in/657910

Comment: Well, if you `var_dump($a=3);` here, it will clearly return `int(3) True` which satisfies the if condition.

Comment: Yes, if it is `3`. If it is false (as demo showed) though it will not `always` be `true`. For example look at the manual, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php, if the assignment were always true `if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES (?)"))) {` wouldn't make sense.