# checking zero is null or not in php

Tags: php

i am working on validation and comparisons!! i have a field that can contain the value `$val=0` or `$val="some-value"` or `$val=""` `or $val=0` basically i want the `$val="0"`or `$val=0` to be validated as true..

```
 if($val){
    //works for $val="some-value"
//doesnot work for $val=0 or $val="0";
    } else
    {
    //works corrent for $val=""
    }
```

one conditional approach i used is

```
$val="";

    if($val || $val==0){
    echo "true";
}
else
{
//should be false but it is true
    echo "false";
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: basically i want the $val="0"or $val=0 and $val="" to be validated as true..

Comment: Then __what__ should __not__ be validated?

Comment: $val=""; should not be validated

Comment: `$val="" to be validated as true.`, `only $val=""; should not be validated` Which is true?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The 3 different equals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals)

Comment: oops my bad i am not getting edit option i will edit it

Comment: meanwhile  $var=""; to be false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try this?

```
$val = "";

if ($val == '0') {
    echo "TRUE";
        # code...
    }   
elseif ($val == "") {
        echo "FALSE";
    }
```

Comment: o thanks man! i was using php functions as i got confused between string and integer comparisons that was so simple thanks...:)

Answer (score 0):

There is a useful php native function [is_null](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php)

```
if (is_null($val) || $val === "") {
    //invalid
} else {
   //valid
}
```

Comment: almost there but it is validating $val=""; as true which i want false

Comment: much appreciated...:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PHP integer casting` & can do it like this:

```
if ((int) $val === 0) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `return empty($val)`

Comment: much appreciated..:)

Comment: @uneeb - If you find this answer correct and helpful then accept or upvote this answer as it motivates me to give answers to other questions like this and helps others to quickly find the correct answer!