# Make a php variable with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Problem and I don't know how to solve it.
I try to make a simple if statement with a php variable. The Variable contains a MySQL SELECT value.

```
$adminarray = $mysqli->query("SELECT admin FROM user WHERE name LIKE '$username'");

$currentuser = mysqli_fetch_row($adminarray);

$adm = $currentuser[0];


echo "<form action='?delete1' method='post' style='visibility:";if ($adm = 1){echo "block";}else{echo "hidden";}echo "'>
```

I try to hide the button for non admins ($adm = 0) but it is not working. The IF Statemant always returns a "true". even if $adm is 0.

I know the code isn't that good, but I'm still learning. So if you can give some tips :)

Thanks for answering

Comment: It's okay that you're still learning, but please try to ask questions clearly. I have no idea what you're asking. See [ask].

Comment: @Chris there is no question asked, actually. He was just wanted some tips.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The 3 different equals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals)

Comment: `if ($adm = 1)` is setting `$adm` to `1`, not comparing it.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, use [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for inline comperison and read about [comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) in PHP

Secondly, do not write a few strings that separated by semicolon together. [Semicolon](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php) in PHP means end of instruction and it's better to write each in new line, so it will be easier to read and maintain the code

Thirdly, always [escape data](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) in SQL queries and check type of variable before indexing it as array([is_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php), [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php))

Finnaly, use IDE (PhpStorm, NetBeans etc) it will help you to prevent doing such mistakes

```
$username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($username);
$adminarray = $mysqli->query("SELECT admin FROM user WHERE name LIKE '$username'");

$currentuser = mysqli_fetch_row($adminarray);

$adm = is_array($currentuser) ? $currentuser[0] : null;
$visibility = $adm == 1 ? "block" : "hidden";

echo "<form action='?delete1' method='post' style='visibility:$visibility'>";
```

It is also worth noting that prepared statements are preferable to plain SQL queries when you are using parameters. In that case code will look slightly different:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT admin FROM user WHERE name LIKE ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_row();
$visibility = (is_array($row) && $row[0] == 1) ? "block" : "hidden";

echo "<form action='?delete1' method='post' style='visibility:$visibility'>";
```

More details about prepared statements you can find here: [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Don't use manual escaping like this. It's more error prone and substantially more verbose than simply using prepared statements and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I feel really stupid right now.
I wrote $adm = 1 instead of $adm == 1.
I'm really sorry for the waste of time.

Comment: You aren't the only one that has been bitten. I think there's a reason that Pascal, PL/I and Oracle PL/SQL use the **`:=`** (colon equals) operator symbol for assignment.