# Unable to save model attribute as null?

Tags: yii2

Here is my model rules

```
public function rules() {
        return [
            [['header_image', 'profil_picture'], 'default', 'value' => null],
            [['yahoo_id', 'whats_app_id', 'bbm_id'], 'string', 'max' => 20],
            [['bbm_id'], 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', 'message' => 'Alpha numeric only'],
            [['header_image_file', 'profil_picture_file'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'extensions' => 'png, jpeg, jpg, bmp', 'maxSize' => 10240 * 20240 * 2],
            [['deskripsi_toko'], 'string', 'max' => 300],
            [['agent_id', 'nama_toko', 'tag_line', 'header_image', 'profil_picture', 'yahoo_id', 'whats_app_id', 'bbm_id', 'deskripsi_toko'], 'filter', 'filter' => function($value) {
                    return BeoHelper::replace_mc($value);
                }],
        ];
    }
```

Here is my controller

```
    $storeSetting->header_image = null;
    if($storeSetting->save()){
      return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer);
    }
```

replace_mc function

```
public static function replace_mc($str)
    {
        $new_data = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\ \.\:\@\+]/', '', $str);
        return $new_data;
    }
```

Record save successfully, but `header_image` is empty string instead of null?

It should set `header_image` as null, Where I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you got this column set as "not null" in database? In this case it is saved as empty string.

Comment: @Bizley no, not null is unchecked in my navicat, maybe the problem with my rules, isn't it?

Comment: I can see this attribute is being filtered by `BeoHelper::replace_mc()` - see if this is not the reason.

Comment: @Bizley yes correct, anyway can you please answer my question. my question is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with additional condition in `replace_mc()`:

```
public static function replace_mc($str)
{
    return $str === null 
        ? $str 
        : preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\ \.\:\@\+]/', '', $str);
}
```

Comment: What's differences with $str == null? thanks in advance.

Comment: When `$str` is `null` it does not proceed with `preg_replace` but returns it as `null`.

Comment: Difference between `==` and `===` is given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2063480/3364821).