# Compare array element in php

Tags: php

I want to compare an array element to wether 0 or 1. For that I want to select my `is_answer_accepted` that is returned by the function `is_answer_accepted($aid)`

```
if($is_answer_accepted['is_answer_accepted'] === 0) {
    delete_all_answer_as_solved($_GET['question']);
    mark_question_as_solved($_GET['answer'], $_GET['question']);
}

if($is_answer_accepted['is_answer_accepted'] === 1) { //Debugger message: $is_answer_accepted: {is_answer_accepted => 0}[1]
    delete_answer_as_solved($_GET['answer'], $_GET['question']);
}
```

I'm clicking on a non accepted answer (confirmed), therefore my `is_answer_accepted` should be 0. Somehow my comparison is failing and `$is_answer_accepted['is_answer_accepted'] = 1` is returning true even tho it is certainly 0.

```
function is_answer_accepted($aid) {
    global $conn;
    $query=$conn->prepare("SELECT is_answer_accepted FROM is_answer_accepted(:aid)");
    $query->execute(array($aid));


    return $query->fetch();
}
```

When I do this query I return 1 if `solved_date != NULL` and 0 otherwise.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_answer_accepted(aid INT)
  returns INTEGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE date_solved TIMESTAMP;
  DECLARE answer_accepted INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT solved_date FROM answers WHERE answers.publicationid = aid
  INTO date_solved;

  IF date_solved is null THEN
    answer_accepted := 0;
  ELSE
    answer_accepted :=1;
  END IF;

  return answer_accepted;
END
$$;
```

The response is:

```
is_answer_accepted
------------------
                 0
(1 row)
```

Any idea how the comparison is wrong?

Kind regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The 3 different equals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals)

Comment: `if($is_answer_accepted['is_answer_accepted'] = 0) {` means you *assign* the value 0 to the variable. See the flagged dupe. You need to compare, using `==` or `===` (strict comparison).

Comment: `=` declares variables, `==` will do a loose comparison and `===` is a strict comparison. I can't remember the ins and outs but I think the `==` does something with dataTypes where `===` has to match dataType and value.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs like the dupe says, `==` will only compare *value*. That might get you some funky responses, because `"string" == true` will actually return a true comparison. `===` needs the same value **and** the same data-type. So `"1" === 1` will fail, because it's a string and an integer.

Comment: @Qirel ah so my hunch was right - just not confirmed haha thanks :)

Comment: My bad, I had `===` , I changed for some desperate debugging. I edited the original content. It still does the incorrect comparison though

Comment: `var_dump($is_answer_accepted['is_answer_accepted'])` and check exactly what it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($is_answer_accepted['is_answer_accepted'] == 0) {
    delete_all_answer_as_solved($_GET['question']);
    mark_question_as_solved($_GET['answer'], $_GET['question']);
}

if($is_answer_accepted['is_answer_accepted'] == 1) { //Debugger message: $is_answer_accepted: {is_answer_accepted => 0}[1]
    delete_answer_as_solved($_GET['answer'], $_GET['question']);
}
```

your if statement include assigning not comparssion

Comment: Please avoid answering questions which are clearly duplicates of existing questions. Also, a code-dump without an explanation isn't a good answer.