# Else statement not executing in php

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

My code always executes if statement, even if the condition is false, it doesn't go to else.

```
<?php 
$link = $count;

if ($link == 8 || 10) {
  echo "<a href='files/".$link.".pdf'>Link</a>";
} else {
  echo "Contact HES sales representative for detailed layout model";
}
?>
```

Comment: Your `if` statement is wrong (and always tests as true). It should be `if($link == 8 || $link == 10)`

Comment: Thankyou so much. Now i understand the theory behind it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `10` is a "truthy" value, the condition will always be true. You basically have

```
if($link == 8 || true) {
```

because `10 == true` is, in fact, true.

You should adapt it to either

```
if ($link == 8 || $link == 10) {
```

or you can use `in_array()` if you start to get many values

```
if (in_array($link, array(8, 10)) {
```

---

If you want, you can use strict comparison - if (and only if) `$link` is an integer. Then you'd have three equalities, which requires the same value **and** the same type. This is because PHP is weakly typed, so it doesn't compare types by default (and as a result you can compare different types and have a valid result). Using strict comparison allows you to better control what type of variables you compare.

```
if ($link === 8 || $link === 10) {
```

- [Proof that `10 == true`](https://3v4l.org/S1nDm)
- [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)
- [Comparison operators in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)
- [The 3 different equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals)

Answer (score 1):

The condition `$link == 8 || 10` will always return true.  If `$link` isn't 8, then it checks if `10` is true.  Any non-zero value is true.

Instead:

```
if ($link == 8 || $link == 10) ...
```

Or if you prefer to check a value in a list:

```
if (in_array($link, [8, 10])) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($link == 8 || 10)
```

// this statement will always be true

because `10` is a non-zero which is asserted as true.

you can do like this `if($link == 8 || $link == 10)` to get this working

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your if part you are defining your if wrong

```
if ($link == 8 || $link == 10) {
  echo "<a href='files/".$link.".pdf'>Link</a>";}
} else {
  echo "Contact HES sales representative for detailed layout model";
}
```