# Why are my PHP "if" conditions being ignored? Break/continue not working

Tags: php

I have the following set of if/elseif conditions that update columns titled `Col` & `Col2` when a form is submitted:

```
if($data3["Col"] < 2 ){

      $db->query("UPDATE answers SET Col = Col+1");

}elseif( $data3["Col"]= 2){
      $db->query("UPDATE answers SET Col = Col+0");
  }

if($data3["Col2"] < 10){

 $db->query("UPDATE answers SET Col2 = Col2+1");

}elseif( $data3["Col2"] >= 10){

      $db->query("UPDATE answers SET Col2 = Col2+0");
 }
```

When the code runs, it ignores the if/elseif conditions and does every update. For example, let's say upon form submit, `Col = 2` & `Col2 = 10`. `Col` and `Col2` should both stay stay the same. However, the code updates both by 1. I've tried every iteration that I can think of using `continue`, `break`, and `return` but nothing seems to work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Your first `elseif` only contains a single `=`. You are assigning 2 to `$data3` rather than checking that it **equals** 2.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you dont want to update anything for `col = 2` and `col2 = 10` then why un-necessary update query is there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The 3 different equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals)

Comment: `if` conditions are not "ignored"; if you stop thinking like that you'll be able to more easily find your bugs

Comment: @kouro Do not edit the answer into the question!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed an equal to here

```
elseif($data3["Col"]==2)
```

Comment: Oh, how vast a difference a petty comma does make. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: It says I need to wait a few minutes to accept. I'll accept when it lets me.

Comment: @user3666954: That is not a comma.

Answer (score 1):

Equal sign (`=`)is for assignment not for testing equality(`==`), so your `elseif` clause should   be  
   `$data3["Col"] == 2` instead of `$data3["Col"]= 2`;

```
if($data3["Col"] < 2 ){

      $db->query("UPDATE answers SET Col = Col+1");

}elseif( $data3["Col"]= 2){// not $data3["Col"]= 2 but this $data3["Col"] == 2
      $db->query("UPDATE answers SET Col = Col+0");
  }
```

Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your help. Completely missed that extra =

Comment: That happens sometimes

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
elseif($data3["Col"]=2){ $db->query("UPDATE answers SET Col = Col+0");}
```

use this:

```
elseif($data3["Col"]==2){ $db->query("UPDATE answers SET Col = Col+0");}
```

Answer (score -1):

you don't need to used elseif for no action ..
just try if for any action...

check `$data3["Col2"]` value. I think your problem is here..