# php Function echo's wrong string

Tags: php, function

I'm fairly new to PHP  so forgive me if this function is badly done.

I have a function:

```
function socialLink($sm_type = NULL) {
   if ($sm_type = 'twitter') {
     echo 'https://www.twitter.com';
   } else {
     echo 'https://www.facebook.com';
   }
}
```

In my code when I call the function `socialLink('facebook');` it echo's the Twitter URL.

Surely it should echo the Facebook URL since `$sm_type` would be equal to `'facebook'` not `twitter` ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your test is a classic error : should be $sm_type == 'twitter'.  As written, you assigne a value to $sm_type, always true.

Comment: Make sure that you read proper documentation about the Comparison Operators (in any programming language): http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Thank you for the link. I could definitely do with revising more of the PHP Manual.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The 3 different equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set your `if` condition with this,

```
function socialLink($sm_type = NULL) {
   if ($sm_type == 'twitter') {
     echo 'https://www.twitter.com';
   } else {
     echo 'https://www.facebook.com';
   }
}
```

See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Comment: It was something so simple all along. Can't believe I couldn't see that. Thank you.

Comment: Happy to help dude. Be careful for small mistakes.
Please accept the answer if you got your output.. Cheerss..!!

Answer (score 3):

```
function socialLink($sm_type = NULL) {

   if ($sm_type == 'twitter') {
     echo 'https://www.twitter.com';
   } else {
     echo 'https://www.facebook.com';
   }
}
```

**NOTE:** Single `=` use to assign the value and `= =` use to compare values

> Different's Between `=` , `= =` , `= = =`

- `=` operator Used to just assign the `value`.
- `= =` operator Used to just compares the `values` not `datatype`
- `= = =` operator Used to Compare the `values` as well as `datatype`.

Answer (score 2):

Your if statement does not use a comparison operator, it is an assignment (=). For a comparison, please use "==".

```
if ($sm_type == 'twitter') {
     echo 'https://www.twitter.com';
} else {
    echo 'https://www.facebook.com';
}
```

Comment: It was something so simple all along. Can't believe I couldn't see that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($sm_type == 'twitter') {
 echo 'https://www.twitter.com';
} else {
echo 'https://www.facebook.com';
}
```

In php == is use for string comparison so, In this case you can't used = for that, simple :)