# My variable iz zero but IF doesn't recognize it?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$check1 = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from Sailors where Name='$habboname'");
$check2 = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from Sailors where Position='$position'");
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($check1);
$num_rows2 = mysqli_num_rows($check2);
if ($num_rows > 0)  {
    echo "This user (<b>" . $habboname . "</b>) is already in our database.";
    exit();
} else {
    if ($num_row2 = 0){
    $sql =  "INSERT INTO Sailors (ID, Name, Joined, Rank, Billet, Position, Status, Promoter, Reason, Promo_Date)
    VALUES ('', '$habboname', '$date', '$rank', '$billet', '$position', 'Active', '$promoter', '$reason', '$date')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        header("Location: useradded.php");
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
} else {
        echo $num_row2;
    }
```

It will always echo, even if the variable IS 0. I am really confused.
If you know what the issue is, please let me know.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are checking the assignment:

```
if ($num_row2 = 0){
```

While you should actually check for equality:

```
if ($num_row2 == 0){
```

Comment: Ohhh! Thank you loads, I don't know how I missed that.

Comment: You are welcome :) Will appreciate if you mark the answer as correct when possible.

Comment: I have to wait 15 minutes, will do. :)

Comment: When doing equality checks, it's better to use `===`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals)

Comment: @ishegg I agree when you don't know the type of the result, but that's not the case here since `mysqli_num_rows` will return the number of the results (0 if no results found).

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($num_row2 = 0){
```

is not ***comparison*** its actually ***assignment***.

So Convert it to:-

```
if ($num_row2 == 0){ //comparison
```

Or

```
if ($num_row2 === 0){ //comparison
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 if ($num_row2 = 0){
```

try to set $num_row2 = 0. Always it can.
You can use this ways:

```
 if ($num_row2 == 0){
```

or expert way:

```
 if (!$num_row2){
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can avoid making an assignment error in PHP when your real intention is to do a comparison is to train yourself to code as follows:

```
if (0 == $num_row2)
```

It may be feel a little awkward at first, but it really can help in avoiding the assignment operator when one intends a comparison based on equality and of course the same technique is good for a comparison based on identity.