# For loop with date('d') or date('j') in php totally bug my navigator

Tags: php

I have a strange issue in my site conception...

I try to create a select with 3 input, one for day, one for month and one for year.
The year input work clean, but, if I try that for day:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= date('t'); $i++) {
  if ($i < 10) {
    $i = '0'. $i;
  }
  if ($i = date('d')) {
    echo '<option selected>'. $i .'</option>';
  } else {
    echo '<option>'. $i .'</option>';
  }
}
```

This bug totally my navigator (Firefox up to date version) and I don't understand why...

Comment: `=` is assignment `==` or `===` are comparison

Comment: Thanks you, i'm very stupid don't see that x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:-

```
if ($i = date('d')) {//it's assignment not comparison
```

To:-

```
if ($i == date('d')) { //or if ($i === date('d')) { now it's comparison
```

Output:-https://eval.in/860475  OR  https://eval.in/860476

Reference:- [The three different equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals)

Comment: Lol... I'm so stupid it's just tha xD
Thanks you very much !

Comment: @MatthyDragneel  glad to help you. Thanks