# Update or delete SQL row based on radio button selection PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to update/delete a SQL row based on the value of a radio button using PHP.

My code looks like the below and so far, when i click the submit button - it does nothing!

```
<form method="post" action="?action">
  <?php
  $stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE Approved="0" ORDER BY id DESC');

  while ($result= $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
  $reviewtitle= $result['Title'];
  $rating= $result['Rating'];
  $name= $result['Name'];
  $date= $result['Date'];
  $review= $result['Review'];
  $ID= $result['ID'];
  $counter = ++$counter;
  ?>

  <br>
  <?php echo $reviewtitle; ?><br>
  <?php echo $rating; ?>
  <br>
  <?php echo $name; ?><br>
  <?php echo $review; ?>
  <p>Posted: <?php echo $date; ?></p>
  <p>Review ID: <input type="text" name="IDNumbers[<?php echo $count; ?>]" value="<?php echo $ID; ?>" readonly></p>

    <input type="radio" name="approved[<?php echo $count; ?>]" value="Approve Review"> Approve Review<br>
    <input type="radio" name="approved[<?php echo $count; ?>]" value="Delete Review"> Delete Review<br>

  </div>
  <br>
  <?php } ?>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

-

```
<?php
    $CurrentID = "";
    if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
        $count2 = $counter;
        while ($count2 > "0"){
        $CurrentID = $_POST["IDNumbers[".$count2."]"];  
            if ($_POST["approved[".$count2."]"] = "Approve Review") {
                    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE reviews SET Approved='1' WHERE (ID=?)");
                    $stmt->execute(array($CurrentID));
            } elseif ($_POST["approved[".$count2."]"] = "Delete Review") {
                    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM reviews WHERE (ID=?)");
                    $stmt->execute(array($CurrentID));
            }
            $count2 = --$count2;
        }
        echo "<h2> Successful!</h2>";
    }
?>
```

There are some other bits of code in this however, it seems like the button does nothing at the moment and I'm really not too sure why. I am new to PHP, so go easy please :)

If anyone can see that this is going to go wrong in other ways, please let me know as I haven't been able to test it yet as the button won't work.

Comment: `$count2`  is never greater than `0`, it is `0`.

Comment: You also have 2 `form`s.

Comment: @chris85, thanks for such a quick response. How do I make it so that $count2 = $counter?

Comment: You did `$counter = $count2 = "0";` but both are equal to `0`. So this condition `while ($count2 > "0"){` is never met.

Comment: Okay, so I changed it to be: <?php
$CurrentID = "";
if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
 $count2 = $counter;
 while ($count2 > "0"){
 $CurrentID = $_POST["IDNumber[".$count2."]"]; 
  if ($_POST["approved[".$count2."]"] = "Approve Review") {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE reviews SET Approved='1' WHERE (ID=?)");
    $stmt->execute(array($CurrentID));
  } elseif ($_POST["approved[".$count2."]"] = "Delete Review") {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM reviews WHERE (ID=?)");
    $stmt->execute(array($CurrentID));
  }
 $count2 = --$count2;
}
echo "<h2> Successful!</h2>";

}
?>

Comment: Can you please `edit` the question, hard to read code in comments. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46208117/edit

Comment: This now gives me the message "Successful!", but it doesn't seem to actually update or delete the row..

Comment: Sorry. Have updated :)

Comment: It looks like you only took out the initialization of `$counter` and `$count2`. Is `$counter` being set earlier?

Comment: It's being set in the second while loop - under the SELECT query - which gets executed before if (isset($_GET['action']))

Comment: This is procedural so it executes in the order you have it so you won't enter the first `while`.

Comment: Do any errors show from http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php also looking at your developer console? @TechyChick94 also looking at your HTML source to see what's being populated.

Comment: Okay, I've updated the code again - it doesn't seem to update or delete rows still...

Comment: Also, `WHERE (ID=?)` - I'd start by removing those brackets, since those are mostly used for subqueries.

Comment: I also noticed that you are assiging `=` rather than comparing `==` in a few conditional statements. That alone will make your code fail. I think that the question may be a duplicate of [The 3 different equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals)

Comment: @chris85 Look at what you missed *lol!* ^

Comment: @chris85 it doesn't help the cause. It won't enter the `while` because the form wasn't submitted (yet). I won't be submitting an answer, so if you want.... go for it ;-) Edit: You deleted your comment I was responding to here, why?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Code was updated, now the `count2` actually is set.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've added in error_reporting(E_ALL); and get Notice: Undefined index: IDNumbers[2] and Undefined index: IDNumbers[1]

Comment: @TechyChick94 You should put some debugging statements in and see which code blocks execute. There are a few different issues going on here and you're going to need to fall the full execution path to see whats what. I'd also use a form for each field and process each submission individually.

Comment: OMG - realised it's 1AM here and I need to be up at 7 - and being a girl, I need my beauty sleep. Will be back on tomorrow guys :) x

Comment: @chris85 thank you I will do. I will let you know how it goes tomorrow.