# password = passwordrepeat? // HTML, PHP, JS

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to make a user registration and found there some Templates and Tutorials. The registration basically works but i really want a field where the user has to repeat his password. My problem now is how to check if the two fields (`password` and `passwordrepeat`) are the same?
Here is my code: 
[image]

Comment: Please do not post a picture of your code, copy it into you question.

Comment: To ask an On Topic questions, please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)
 **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write code for you**

Comment: You're already using an API that supports **prepared statements** with bounded variable input, you should utilize parameterized queries with placeholders (prepared statements) to protect your database against [SQL-injection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)!
 Get started with [`mysqli::prepare()`](http://php.net/mysqli.prepare) and [`mysqli_stmt::bind_param()`](http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.bind-param).

Comment: Using old methods of encrypting passwords (such as `sha1`, `md5`) are **poor methods of hashing** - you should use newer methods for hashing your passwords. PHP has a built-in [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function 
which is a lot more secure!

Comment: To check if two things are equal, you compare them. `$a == $b` is true if they are equal. Have a look at [**The 3 different equals**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compare the two POST vars and check if they are equals.

```
if($_POST['password'] === $_POST['passwordrepeat']){
    /* Do your registration */
} else {
    /* return an error */
}
```

Obviously you have to check for the existence of those vars, and do all the security stuff.

Comment: Thank you this helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML Code:

```
<input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" min="6" max="30" required="" placeholder="Mot de passe">
<input type="password" name="cpass" id="cpass" min="6" max="30" required="" placeholder="Confirmation">
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_POST['pass']) AND !empty($_POST['cpass']) AND $_POST['pass'] == $_POST['cpass'])
    {   
        echo "ok";
    }
    else
    {
        include("index.php");
        ?>
        <style>
        #cpass
        {
            border: 3px solid red;
            border-radius:6px;
        }
        </style>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
```

You can also use JS.

Comment: I have found the solution now but thank you for your time :)